# How can I prevent GCC optimizing some statements in C?

Tags: c, gcc

In order to make a page dirty (switching on the dirty bit in the page table entry), I touch the first bytes of the page like this:

```
pageptr[0] = pageptr[0];
```

But in practice, GCC will ignore the statement by dead store elimination. In order to prevent GCC optimizing it, I rewrite the statement as follows:

```
volatile int tmp;
tmp = pageptr[0];
pageptr[0] = tmp;
```

It seems the trick works, but somewhat ugly. I would like to know is there any directives or syntax which has the same effect? And I don't want to use a [-O0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O0) flag, since it will bring great performance penalty as well.

Comment: @Mark -O0 will stop the optimization, but also slows down program performance. I just want to prevent optimization of this code snippet :P

Comment: I would like to add that in the past, even using `-O0` did not prevent dead code "optimization", e.g., when GCC detects some code has no effect, it simply removes it. AFAIK this is a stage even before `-O0`... But that's just my experience

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Turning off optimization fixes the problem, but it is unnecessary.  A safer alternative is to make it illegal for the compiler to optimize out the store by using the `volatile` type qualifier.

```
// Assuming pageptr is unsigned char * already...
unsigned char *pageptr = ...;
((unsigned char volatile *)pageptr)[0] = pageptr[0];
```

The `volatile` type qualifier instructs the compiler to be strict about memory stores and loads.  One purpose of `volatile` is to let the compiler know that the memory access has side effects, and therefore must be preserved.  In this case, the store has the side effect of causing a page fault, and you want the compiler to preserve the page fault.

This way, the surrounding code can still be optimized, and your code is portable to other compilers which don't understand GCC's `#pragma` or `__attribute__` syntax.

Comment: I would say this is preferable to turning off optimizations. You can still benefit from other optimizations using this method.

Comment: Do you really need to do a load from the page, though? Surely just the store would do: `*(volatile int *)pageptr = 0;`

Comment: You need to modify the program which will make it humanly unreadable.

Comment: @caf - your version could cause the contents of the page to change.  The OP implies that the page contents should not change.

Comment: True, I read something into it that wasn't there (of course, the given solution here also would change the page, if the type of `pageptr[0]` is wider than `char`).

Comment: @caf - missed the int/char issue.  @DietrichEpp - it looks like your fix should be `*(unsigned char volatile *)pageptr = *(unsigned char *)pageptr;`

Comment: Dietrich Epp's solution is not working under **ARM4.1 compiler**. Even ZelluX's solution is not working.
Alternative method to make this work for ARM4.1 is in ZelluX's solution, make '**temp**' a **global volatile variable**.

Comment: That's pretty bad for said compiler.

Comment: This doesn't work for `GCC 6.2.0` with `-O2`. My code `volatile Object* obj = ...` and result `obj = <optimised out>`

Comment: @Shocker: GCC can still optimize out the variable without optimizing out the actual memory access. Those are different issues.

Comment: *"One purpose of volatile is to let the compiler know that the memory access has side effects..."* - Under GCC that is not true. The GCC folks state the purpose of `volatile` is for memory mapped hardware. From Ian Lance Taylor's blog on [volatile](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/154): *"In summary, if you are using volatile for anything other than manipulating memory mapped hardware, or for very limited communication between threads, it is very likely that you are making a mistake. Think carefully about what volatile means and about what it does not mean."*

Comment: @jww: this usage fits with what is described in that blog post. `volatile` means that the memory access must occur as written, which is exactly what we want. In other words, we have thought carefully about it, and it means what we think it means.

Comment: then why call it "volatile"...it really means the opposite of "exactly what we want" or "strict"

Comment: @pf12345678910: One reason why access is strict is because the underlying memory may change depending on when it is read. In other words, it is a “volatile” memory location that may change even when you don’t write to it. Because the variable is volatile, the access must be done in a precise, strict way.

Comment: no I mean volatile means it will evaporate, which is the opposite of strict

Comment: @pf12345678910: The variable is volatile. If you write a value to it, you might read a **different** value back. The value that you wrote evaporated, because the variable is volatile.

Comment: With nonvolatile memory, when you write a value, you get the same value back afterwards. It sticks around.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: That depends.  Some kinds of non-volatile storage may only be written if they hold 0xFF, except when using a special mechanism to reset a large range of storage to 0xFF.

Comment: @supercat: The word `volatile` can mean something different in different contexts. The context here is the C language, so we’re trying to understand what the `volatile` keyword means here. If you have non-volatile memory of some kind and you want to write to it from C, paradoxically, you need the `volatile` keyword for that.

Comment: C’s notion of `volatile` is that loads and stores have some *other* effect, besides just making it so that you can read the same value back afterwards, during the same program run. If you have EEPROM or something, then one effect of writing a value is that you flip bits to zero, another effect is that you can read the EEPROM later after turning the power off and back on. Hence, `volatile`, by C standards.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The lack of a `volatile` qualfier means that a *compiler* may assume that anything its generated code writes to a storage location will still be there the next time its generated code reads that location, but a compiler may process source code that stores a value in ways that don't actually create, much less store, the value anywhere, so there might not be anything that could stick around.

Comment: @supercat This topic has already been discussed elsewhere, I don’t think this is a good place to try and replicate the discussion. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c

Answer (score 238):

You can use

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")

your code

#pragma GCC pop_options
```

to disable optimizations since GCC 4.4.

See the GCC documentation if you need more details.

Comment: It is worth noting however that this only works on entire functions, not on specific statments: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html "Each function that is defined after this point is as if attribute((optimize("STRING"))) was specified for that function.".

Comment: Can you do the reverse to optimise a single function only @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com

Comment: @rollsch I'd try `pragma GCC optimize ("O3")`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222127/what-does-pragma-gcc-optimize-o3-mean

Answer (score 179):

Instead of using the new pragmas, you can also use `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))` for your needs. This has the advantage of just applying to a single function and not all functions defined in the same file.

Usage example:

```
void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) foo(unsigned char data) {
    // unmodifiable compiler code
}
```

Comment: What if I am not using a`-Olevel`option but I used the individuals options it turns on separetely? *(In my case, I can't determine which is the individual optimization option which is breaking the code)*.

Comment: None of the recommendations around volatile work any more. GCC compiler headers cannot handle volatile + O0. While loops are optimized out as -faggressive-loop-optimization is default, only O0 blocks this.

For these reasons, O0 and no volatile in the unoptimized function is now the correct answer.

Comment: To update for C23, you can also use the attribute specifier syntax introduced in the new standard: `[[gnu::optimize("O0")]] void foo()`. The same goes for C++11 and newer.