# Is there a way to tell GCC not to optimise a particular piece of code?

Tags: optimization, gcc

I am working on a project that relies on compiler optimisations but I need some code not to be optimised by GCC. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent gcc optimizing some statements in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-to-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GCC has since 4.4. the `#pragma GCC optimize ("whatever")`. I would also recommend to wrap the particular code, that is annotated with this pragma with `#pragma GCC push_options` and `#pragma GCC pop_options`. The first will save the options as they were before your change, the later will restore them afterwards and the rest of the code will compile with the *global* options.

For details on the  *whatever* string, you should look into the gcc doc, here the most important part of it: `Arguments can either be numbers or strings. Numbers are assumed to be an optimization level. Strings that begin with O are assumed to be an optimization option, while other options are assumed to be used with a -f prefix.`.

That means if you dont want any optimizations on your particular code your *whatever* should just be "0".

Comment: I've tried that by I got an "#pragma GCC optimize is not allowed inside functions" error. Is it possible to enable/disable optimisations inside a function scope?

Comment: @limp: oh no, that does not work. This pragma makes practically nothing than add the corrosponding attribute flag to the function(s). So if you really want to change options on a small part of a function you have at least to move it to an own subfuction. Its not possible to make inside functions, as many optimizations work on whole functions and technically it isnt possible to change the behaviour of just some parts of it.

Comment: Ok, so AFAIU that means that #pragma GCC optimize has a file scope. If I put in the beggining of a source file #pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0") and then #pragma GCC pop_options in the end of the file, I guess all the code/functions that is contained in this file, will not be optimised, am I right?

Comment: @limb: Yes, beginning and end will treat the whole file. But you can make it more fine granular. The granularity is function - i.e. you can optimize functions in a file different (you have to declare between the functions) - you just cant do it inside function to treat a single function different.

Comment: It's worth to note that Clang also works with `#pragma GCC` for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 34):

GCC 4.4 has an attribute for that:

```
int foo(int i) __attribute__((optimize("-O3")));
```

It is documented at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007boptimize_007d-function-attribute-3195

Comment: Excellent! That worked great! I was wondering if I add the attribute into a function, does it apply in all its subfunctions as well or only in the function's locally executed code?

Comment: @limp Only in the function body (how else, because it could call functions that are called from _other_ places that _do_ have optimizations enabled...)

Comment: Do you really need the hyphen before O3?

Comment: In GCC 9.1 for ARM, the compiler complained and asked for the attribute to be before the  declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You can put that piece of code into a different file and compile it without optimisations.

Or try to use the #pragma directive:

```
#pragma optimize level=0
```

Or even better start and stop optimization with :

```
#pragma OPTIMIZE ON 
#pragma OPTIMIZE OFF
```

Comment: Is there something I should do in order to enable compiler support for #pragma directives or it comes by default on GGC >= 4.4?

Comment: Are all of the following supported by GCC?:

#pragma GCC optimize 1
#pragma GCC optimize 0

#pragma OPTIMIZE OFF
#pragma OPTIMIZE ON

#pragma optimize ("", off)
#pragma optimize ("", on)

Also, can I use these pragmas inside functions?

Comment: @limp: depends on your gcc version. @fiolo pointed out that is from 4.4 .

Comment: Also on the platform it seems.  On Raspbian (armv7l) these are not supported despite GCC is version 4.9.2 :(.   `__attribute__` seems to work.