# How can I prevent GCC from optimizing out a busy wait loop?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, avr-gcc

I want to write a C code firmware for Atmel AVR microcontrollers. I will compile it using GCC. Also, I want to enable compiler optimizations (`-Os` or `-O2`), as I see no reason to not enable them, and they will probably generate a better assembly way faster than writing assembly manually.

But I want a small piece of code not optimized. I want to delay the execution of a function by some time, and thus I wanted to write a do-nothing loop just to waste some time. No need to be precise, just wait some time.

```
/* How can it NOT optimize this, while optimizing other code? */
unsigned char i, j;
j = 0;
while(--j) {
    i = 0;
    while(--i);
}
```

Since memory access in AVR is a lot slower, I want `i` and `j` to be kept in CPU registers.

---

I found [util/delay.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) and [util/delay_basic.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay__basic.html) from [AVR Libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/). Although most times it might be a better idea to use those functions, this question remains valid and interesting.

---

Related questions:

- *[How can I prevent GCC optimizing some statements in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2219829)*
- *[Is there a way to tell GCC not to optimise a particular piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5580140)*
- [How not to optimize away - mechanics of a folly function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28287064)

Comment: Maybe there's some sort of a "Sleep" syscall?  Maybe you can just embed some assembly logic?

Comment: Why not to insert something like `volatile asm ("rep; nop;")` to busy-pause by wasting CPU cycles that do nothing?

Comment: Why not putting this piece of code in a function and compiling it with '-O0' separately from the rest of your '-O2' code? And linking them together obviously.

Comment: @George: Just checked. `avr-libc` has no sleep function that just waits some time. Instead, it maps to CPU `sleep` instruction, which starts one of the low-power modes (effectively stopping the CPU). Good idea, nevertheless.

Comment: People, you are giving solutions in the comments! Add them as answers! :)

Comment: what version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @Denilson - mostly because they're not full fledged answers, only suggestions on what to try.

Comment: @Foo Bah: right now, gcc 4.5.2

Comment: @Denilson I asked a question, you answering it will maybel lead to a full length answer :)

Comment: @stavnir Well... The only reason to not do that is the amount of extra work required (adding an extra file, changing the Makefile to compile that file with different flags). But, still, your question is already a good answer.

Comment: @Vlad: there is no `rep` in AVR instruction set. What was it supposed to be?

Comment: @Denilson: I don't know AVR assembly, that's why I said "something like". There should be something similar, no?

Comment: @Vlad: that's what I asked. What is `rep`? What assembly language were you thinking about when you wrote that? I can't say if there is anything similar if I don't know what you meant in the first place! ;)

Comment: @Denilson: REP - repeat, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings
BTW, here is how to pause on ARM, see (PAUSE, NOP defines) - http://doc.bertos.org/2.6/attr_8h_source.html

Comment: @Vlad: Thanks, but even on x86, it seems `rep` can't be used together with `nop`. And, no, there is no such thing on AVR.

Comment: @Denilson: It not only __can__ be used, but is actually used all over the place. I've just posted you an example of alternative instructions for ARM.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I developed this answer after following a link from [dmckee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-compiler-optimization-on-a-small-piece-of-code/7083880#7083880), but it takes a different approach than his/her answer.

[Function Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) documentation from GCC mentions:

> `noinline`
>   This function attribute prevents a function from being considered for inlining.  If the function does not have side-effects, there are optimizations other than inlining that causes function calls to be optimized away, although the function call is live. To keep such calls from being optimized away, put `asm ("");`

This gave me an interesting idea... Instead of adding a `nop` instruction at the inner loop, I tried adding an empty assembly code in there, like this:

```
unsigned char i, j;
j = 0;
while(--j) {
    i = 0;
    while(--i)
        asm("");
}
```

And it worked! That loop has not been optimized-out, and no extra `nop` instructions were inserted.

What's more, if you use `volatile`, gcc will store those variables in RAM and add a bunch of `ldd` and `std` to copy them to temporary registers. This approach, on the other hand, doesn't use `volatile` and generates no such overhead.

---

*Update:* If you are compiling code using `-ansi` or `-std`, you must replace the `asm` keyword with `__asm__`, as [described in GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html).

In addition, you can also use `__asm__ __volatile__("")` if your [*assembly statement must execute where we put it, (i.e. must not be moved out of a loop as an optimization)*](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4).

Comment: How would you do this in visual studio? `__asm{""}` will not work

Comment: I'm a bit concerned with loop unrolling, I would recommend this version with explicit data dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58758133/895245

Answer (score 34):

Declare `i` and `j` variables as `volatile`. This will prevent the compiler to optimize code involving these variables.

```
unsigned volatile char i, j;
```

Comment: Although this works, it has a side-effect of forcing those variables into memory. Thus, GCC will read and write them on every loop iteration, adding quite a lot of overhead. (anyway, if I want extremely fine-grained control, I should write assembly directly)

Comment: @DenilsonSá On the other hand, forcing a memory access will ensure the wait always takes the same time, independently if the value is 16bits encodable or not.

Comment: @Oswin, can you please elaborate? What do you mean by "if the value is 16bits encodable or not". What is the "value" you are talking about? And encodable into what?

Comment: Just curious, could you mark them as `volatile register` to avoid them getting put in memory?

Comment: Not a good idea as writing those variables to memory every time adds extra delay and therefore is less fine grained than a loop with a register loop counter, not to mention that it puts stress on the cache / databus while all you want to do is "nothing".

Answer (score 12):

**Empty `__asm__` statements are not enough: better use data dependencies**

Like this:

#### File *main.c*

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        __asm__ volatile("" : "+g" (i) : :);

    }
}
```

Compile and disassemble:

```
gcc -O3 -ggdb3 -o main.out main.c
gdb -batch -ex 'disas main' main.out
```

Output:

```
   0x0000000000001040 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001042 <+2>:     nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001048 <+8>:     add    $0x1,%eax
   0x000000000000104b <+11>:    cmp    $0x9,%eax
   0x000000000000104e <+14>:    jbe    0x1048 <main+8>
   0x0000000000001050 <+16>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001052 <+18>:    retq
```

I believe that this is robust, because it places an explicit data dependency on the loop variable `i` as suggested at: [Enforcing statement order in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c) and produces the desired loop:

This marks `i` as an input and output of inline assembly. Then, inline assembly is a black box for GCC, which cannot know how it modifies `i`, so I think that really can't be optimized away.

If I do the same with an empty `__asm__` as in:

#### File *bad.c*

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        __asm__ volatile("");
    }
}
```

it appears to completely remove the loop and outputs:

```
   0x0000000000001040 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001042 <+2>:     retq
```

Also note that `__asm__("")` and `__asm__ volatile("")` should be the same since there are no output operands: [The difference between asm, asm volatile and clobbering memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449141/the-difference-between-asm-asm-volatile-and-clobbering-memory)

What is happening becomes clearer if we replace it with:

```
__asm__ volatile("nop");
```

which produces:

```
   0x0000000000001040 <+0>:     nop
   0x0000000000001041 <+1>:     nop
   0x0000000000001042 <+2>:     nop
   0x0000000000001043 <+3>:     nop
   0x0000000000001044 <+4>:     nop
   0x0000000000001045 <+5>:     nop
   0x0000000000001046 <+6>:     nop
   0x0000000000001047 <+7>:     nop
   0x0000000000001048 <+8>:     nop
   0x0000000000001049 <+9>:     nop
   0x000000000000104a <+10>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000000104c <+12>:    retq
```

So we see that GCC just [loop unrolled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) the `nop` loop in this case because the loop was small enough.

So, if you rely on an empty `__asm__`, you would be relying on hard to predict GCC binary size/speed tradeoffs, which if applied optimally, should would always remove the loop for an empty `__asm__ volatile("");` which has code size zero.

**`noinline` busy loop function**

If the loop size is not known at compile time, full unrolling is not possible, but GCC could still decide to unroll in chunks, which would make your delays inconsistent.

Putting that together with [Denilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084193/895245), a busy loop function could be written as:

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) busy_loop(unsigned max) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        __asm__ volatile("" : "+g" (i) : :);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    busy_loop(10);
}
```

which disassembles at:

```
Dump of assembler code for function busy_loop:
   0x0000000000001140 <+0>:     test   %edi,%edi
   0x0000000000001142 <+2>:     je     0x1157 <busy_loop+23>
   0x0000000000001144 <+4>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001146 <+6>:     nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001150 <+16>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000001153 <+19>:    cmp    %eax,%edi
   0x0000000000001155 <+21>:    ja     0x1150 <busy_loop+16>
   0x0000000000001157 <+23>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001040 <+0>:     mov    $0xa,%edi
   0x0000000000001045 <+5>:     callq  0x1140 <busy_loop>
   0x000000000000104a <+10>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000000104c <+12>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Here the `volatile` is was needed to mark the assembly as potentially having side effects, since in this case we have an output variables.

A double loop version could be:

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) busy_loop(unsigned max, unsigned max2) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < max2; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            __asm__ volatile ("" : "+g" (i), "+g" (j) : :);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    busy_loop(10, 10);
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/a06672a20d160c1748223665501ca45295008423/userland/gcc/busy_loop.c).

Related threads:

- [Endless loop in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186809/endless-loop-in-c-c)
- [Best way to implement busy loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620239/best-way-to-implement-busy-loop)
- [Enforcing statement order in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c/56865717#56865717)

Tested in [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) and GCC 8.3.0.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why it hasn't been mentioned yet that this approach is completely misguided and easily broken by compiler upgrades, etc. It would make a lot more sense to determine the time value you want to wait until and spin polling the current time until the desired value is exceeded. On x86 you could use `rdtsc` for this purpose, but the more portable way would be to call `clock_gettime` (or the variant for your non-POSIX OS) to get the time. Current x86_64 Linux will even avoid the syscall for `clock_gettime` and use `rdtsc` internally. Or, if you can handle the cost of a syscall, just use `clock_nanosleep` to begin with...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know off the top of my head if the AVR version of the compiler supports the [full set of `#pragma`s](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) (the interesting ones in the link all date from GCC version 4.4), but that is where you would usually start.

Comment: Do you happen to know which GCC option enables/disables optimizing-out that do-nothing loop? I tried using `#pragma GCC optimize 0` (followed by `#pragma GCC reset_options` after the function), but it disabled ALL optimizations (as expected). It would have been better to disable just that one.

Comment: pragma only works for subsequently defined functions (and works at the function level).

Comment: I mean... `optimize 0` was too much, it didn't even store those variables in registers (they were kept in memory). So, if I knew which gcc `-f` option disables the removing of that do-nothing loop, I could disable only that option for that function. That would be great!

Answer (score 3):

For me, on GCC 4.7.0, empty assembly code was optimized away anyway with [-O3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O3) (I didn’t try with [-O2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O2)).
and using a i++ in *register* or *volatile* resulted in a big performance penalty (in my case).

I linked with another empty function which the compiler couldn’t see when compiling the "main program".

Basically this:

I created "helper.c" with this function declared (empty function):

```
void donotoptimize(){}
```

Then compiled `gcc helper.c -c -o helper.o`
and then

```
while (...) { donotoptimize();}
```

and link it via `gcc my_benchmark.cc helper.o`.

This gave me best results (and from my belief, no overhead at all, but I can't test because my program won't work without it :) )

I think it should work with [ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler) too. Maybe not if you enable linking optimizations, but with GCC it does.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I linked a "helper.o" with empty function  declared to my `benchmark.c`, but gcc still optimize the loop in `benchmark.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Putting volatile asm should help.
You can read more on this here:

*[Problems with reordering code](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/optimization.html)*

If you are working on Windows, you can even try putting the code under pragmas, as explained in detail below:

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/MSC06-CPP.+Be+aware+of+compiler+optimization+when+dealing+with+sensitive+data

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7083874/1593077), usiing `volatile` has the side effect of forcing these variables into memory, with LD and ST instructions.

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer.

Comment: The second link is broken: *"Page Not Found"*

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 8 years ago"*

Answer (score 0):

Put that loop in a separate .c file and do not optimize that one file.  Even better, write that routine in assembler and call it from C. Either way, the optimizer won’t get involved.

I sometimes do the volatile thing but normally create an asm function that simply returns
put a call to that function the optimizer will make the *for*/*while* loop tight, but it won’t optimize it out because it has to make all the calls to the dummy function.  The nop answer from Denilson Sá does the same thing, but even tighter...

Comment: Nice idea. Can you show example how to do it? I never understood these makefiles...

Comment: @Kamil, a very short explanation, run `gcc -c [your flags here] -o foo.o foo.c` to compile the source into an object, then run `gcc [other flags here] -o foo.elf foo.o bar.o` to link all object files together. Feel free to check the `Makefile`s from my AVR projects: [atmega8-blinking-leds](http://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/atmega8-blinking-leds/src/tip/Makefile.tpl), [atmega8-hidkeys-helloworld](http://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/atmega8-hidkeys-helloworld/src/tip/Makefile), [atmega8-magnetometer-usb-mouse](http://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/atmega8-magnetometer-usb-mouse/src/tip/firmware/Makefile)

Comment: The problem with the compile-separately approach is that it introduces the overhead of a function call and return, which can be quite a bit for the very short wait loops that this sort of thing is useful for.

Comment: the problem with volatile is that it causes the overhead of volatile which can be quite a bit for the very short wait loops that this sort of thing is useful for.  The right answer is to just do this in pure asm and not mess with volatile or inline, but since this kind of timing is not generally accurate, definitely not if you are using C, then a little longer or shorter is fine.  If you want to be more accurate you have to use dedicated hardware to time things.

Comment: Denilson didn't answer, only posed the question and added some comments (including deleted answers). What does it refer to?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the [**register** keyword](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html#register). Variables declared with register are stored in CPU registers.

In your case:

```
register unsigned char i, j;
j = 0;
while(--j) {
    i = 0;
    while(--i);
}
```

Comment: Reserving 2 of 32 microcontroller registers for silly loop is bad idea.