# Best way to implement busy loop?

Tags: c, linux

What is the best way to implement the busy loop ? correct me if i am wrong ?

```
while (1); // obviously eats CPU. 
while (1) { sleep(100); } // Not sure if it is the correct way ?
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you're trying to simulate a heavy thread, it's right.

Comment: you can sleep(1) if you only want to yield to OS instead of throttling.

Comment: Mat, my tiny application associates SIGUSR1, and some other signals with user define signal handler. and i want the main program not to die.

Comment: @user916439: If you want your app to do nothing, _busy looping_ is what you want to **avoid**. That term is used to describe code the uses CPU continually while waiting for something to happen. Your second piece of code is much better if you just want to do nothing without consuming CPU.

Comment: `sleep()` is NOT what is called a 'busy loop'. You can't busy sleeping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do an infinite wait, for a signal (what else) there is the `pause()` system call. You'll have to put it in a loop, as it returns (always with -1 and errno set to EINTR) every time a signal is delivered:

```
while (1)
    pause();
```

As a curious note, this is, AFAIK the only POSIX function documented to *always* fail.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to dmckee, in the comments below, `sigsuspend()` also fails always. It does just the same as `pause()`, but it is more signal-friendly. The difference is that it has parameters, so it can fail with `EFAULT` in addition to `EINTR`.

Comment: It is in `unistd.h`. Please see `man 2 pause` or `man 3 pause` for details, or see it [online](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pause.html).

Comment: Nice. However, the man page on my Mac OS 10.5 box says *" Pause is made obsolete by sigsuspend(2)."* (which also seem to exhibit the always fail behavior and conforms to POSIX.1). Take that for what you will.

Comment: @dmckee Well, obsolete is such an awful word, it is still not deprecated, though. But yes, `sigsuspends()` always fails too, so I'm updating my trivial database...

Comment: It could be worse...`getpass` [was "LEGACY" in SUSv2 and has actually been *removed* from  POSIX](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpass) but *doesn't* have a universal replacement!

Answer (score 3):

Busy loop is loop that never blocks and continuously checks some condition. Small sleep is good enough to avoid 100% cpu usage.
The best way to implement busy wait is to not implement it. Instead of it you can use blocking calls or callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Linux has had the (POSIX 1.g) **pselect** for some time now. If you are using signal handlers or user-defined signals, I think this is worth investigating. It also addresses some subtle race conditions that manifest in other approaches.

I know you mentioned the 'busy loop', but I think a 'blocking loop' is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

**How to prevent it from being optimized away with data dependencies**

First of course, you should only use busy loops if you have very good reason to not use non-busy ones, which are generally more efficient, see: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/using-a-for-loop-or-sleeping-to-wait-for-short-intervals-of-time

Now, focusing only on busy loops, if you just write something like:

```
while (1);
```

or:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; i++);
```

then both of those can be optimized away as mentioned at: [Are compilers allowed to eliminate infinite loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops)

For this reason, as explained in detail at: [How to prevent GCC from optimizing out a busy wait loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-gcc-from-optimizing-out-a-busy-wait-loop/58758133#58758133) I would write them as:

```
while (1) asm("");
```

or:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("" : "+g" (i) : :);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! FWIW I found this useful to read more on `__asm__` syntax used here: https://www.felixcloutier.com/documents/gcc-asm.html