# How to prevent optimization of busy-wait

Tags: compiler-optimization

I need to have a function busy-wait.

```
for(long int j=0; j<50000000; ++j)
  ;
```

When I compile in release mode, this gets optimized out. Other than compiling in debug mode, is there some way to cause this to *not* get optimized out? I don't particularly care about the actual number of the loop, but it **must** be a noticeable busy-delay.

Comment: @SLaks That is not *busy*. I want to keep using the CPU.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent compiler optimization on a small piece of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-compiler-optimization-on-a-small-piece-of-code)

Comment: What language? C++? Java? Perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you need to keep the CPU busy, but let's assume that you really have a good reason, like making sure you keep the CPU busy so it doesn't think about that breakup it went through last week and get all depressed but I digress...

The problem you are seeing is that the compiler performs "dead code elimination": it sees that the loop does nothing (i.e. has no side-effects) and so cuts it out. So you could make it have a side-effect.

A simple solution would be this function:

```
void busywait(long iterations)
{
    for(volatile long i = 0; i != iterations; i++)
        ;
}
```

By marking `i` as `volatile` you are ensuring that the loop has side-effects, since stores to volatile objects (i.e. the incrementing we perform) are treated as having side-effects.

Comment: It now gets optimized to the equivalent of `i += iterations;`

Comment: You could always selectively disable optimizations for that particular function. But in all seriousness, you can tweak the code of the loop so that it has side-effects that the compiler cannot optimize away.

Comment: As a sidenote (four months after the fact) I find it hard to believe that a conforming compiler would optimize the loop to the equivalent of `i += iterations` because every single `+=` will have a side-effect that the standard requires be visible, and coalescing them into one `+=` misses out on `iterations - 1` side-effects.