# How exactly does gcc do optimizations?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

In order to know how exactly the gcc do the optimization, I have written two program compiling with -O2, but there is some difference of the assembly code. In my programs, I want to output "hello" in the loop, and add some delay between each output. These two programs are only for illustrating my question, and I know I can using volatile or asm in program 1 to achieve my purpose.

Program 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (++i > 0x1fffffffUL) {
            printf("hello\n");
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile with -O2, the assembly code is:

```
Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <_main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
   e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  10:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  17:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1c <_main+0x1c>
  1c:   eb f2                   jmp    10 <_main+0x10>
  1e:   90                      nop
  1f:   90                      nop
```

Program 2

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (i > 0x1fffffffUL) {
            printf("hello\n");
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Compile with -O2, the assembly code is:

```
Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <_main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
   e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  10:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  13:   3d ff ff ff 1f          cmp    $0x1fffffff,%eax
  18:   76 f6                   jbe    10 <_main+0x10>
  1a:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
    while (1) {
        if (i > 0x1fffffffUL) {
            printf("hello\n");
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
  21:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   26 <_main+0x26>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (i > 0x1fffffffUL) {
  26:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  28:   eb e6                   jmp    10 <_main+0x10>
            printf("hello\n");
  2a:   90                      nop
  2b:   90                      nop
  2c:   90                      nop
  2d:   90                      nop
  2e:   90                      nop
  2f:   90                      nop
```

In program 1, the increase of `i` is optimized out, but it's not in program 2. Why this happens? What rules is gcc using when optimizing with -O2 for these two programs?

Comment: probably because your program loops forever?

Comment: I think this is because in general it is very hard to detect at compile time that a logic has no impact on the behavior. In some, rare cases it is possible, in most cases not. Your program 1 seems to be one of the lucky cases. Program 2 not.

Comment: Feel free to file an enhancement request on gcc's bugzilla. Note that when you test optimizations, you should avoid the function `main`: the compiler knows it is only ever called once, and sometimes optimizes it less because of that (not this time apparently).

Comment: It's a bug, and I have file it to gcc's bugzilla, refer to [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70041). I think it maybe fixed later.

Answer (score 9):

Asking "why" about optimizers is usually a waste of time, because there *are* no "rules" by which optimizers operate -- other than "as if": The optimizer may not change the observable behaviour of conforming code.

The "observable behaviour" of both your programs is to print "hello" repeatedly.

In your first program, the counting is optimized away, making the observable behaviour happen faster. *That is the job of an optimizer.* Be happy your code is more efficient now!

In your second program, the counting is *not* optimized away, because somehow the optimizer -- in **this** version of **this** compiler with **this** setting -- did not see that it could do without it. Why? Who knows (other than the maintainer of the compiler's optimizer module)?

If your *desired* behaviour is to have a delay between outputs, use something like [thrd_sleep()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep). Empty count loops were a way to delay BASIC 2.0 programs on the C64, but they should not be used in C, for the exact reason you just observed: You never know what the optimizer does.

Answer (score 2):

The branching in the if statement now depends on something that happened in the previous iteration of the loop. In particular, the compiler can easily determine in program 1 that `i` is incremented in every iteration of the while loop (as it is right at the top), while this is not the case in program 2.

Anyway, compiler optimizations are very complicated. See below:

gcc -O2 is a shortcut for these flags: (from the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html))

```
      -fauto-inc-dec 
      -fbranch-count-reg 
      -fcombine-stack-adjustments 
      -fcompare-elim 
      -fcprop-registers 
      -fdce 
      -fdefer-pop 
      -fdelayed-branch 
      -fdse 
      -fforward-propagate 
      -fguess-branch-probability 
      -fif-conversion2 
      -fif-conversion 
      -finline-functions-called-once 
      -fipa-pure-const 
      -fipa-profile 
      -fipa-reference 
      -fmerge-constants 
      -fmove-loop-invariants 
      -freorder-blocks 
      -fshrink-wrap 
      -fsplit-wide-types 
      -fssa-backprop 
      -fssa-phiopt 
      -ftree-bit-ccp 
      -ftree-ccp 
      -ftree-ch 
      -ftree-coalesce-vars 
      -ftree-copy-prop 
      -ftree-dce 
      -ftree-dominator-opts 
      -ftree-dse 
      -ftree-forwprop 
      -ftree-fre 
      -ftree-phiprop 
      -ftree-sink 
      -ftree-slsr 
      -ftree-sra 
      -ftree-pta 
      -ftree-ter 
      -funit-at-a-time
      -fthread-jumps 
      -falign-functions  -falign-jumps 
      -falign-loops  -falign-labels 
      -fcaller-saves 
      -fcrossjumping 
      -fcse-follow-jumps  -fcse-skip-blocks 
      -fdelete-null-pointer-checks 
      -fdevirtualize -fdevirtualize-speculatively 
      -fexpensive-optimizations 
      -fgcse  -fgcse-lm  
      -fhoist-adjacent-loads 
      -finline-small-functions 
      -findirect-inlining 
      -fipa-cp 
      -fipa-cp-alignment 
      -fipa-sra 
      -fipa-icf 
      -fisolate-erroneous-paths-dereference 
      -flra-remat 
      -foptimize-sibling-calls 
      -foptimize-strlen 
      -fpartial-inlining 
      -fpeephole2 
      -freorder-blocks-algorithm=stc 
      -freorder-blocks-and-partition -freorder-functions 
      -frerun-cse-after-loop  
      -fsched-interblock  -fsched-spec 
      -fschedule-insns  -fschedule-insns2 
      -fstrict-aliasing -fstrict-overflow 
      -ftree-builtin-call-dce 
      -ftree-switch-conversion -ftree-tail-merge 
      -ftree-pre 
      -ftree-vrp 
      -fipa-ra
```

Each of these flags corresponds to a different possible optimization the compiler is allowed to make.