# Why this breakpoint is not hit when I run the application without a std::cout printout

Tags: c#, c++, debugging

This is a very strange problem here:

I have a solution that consists of two projects, one is C# and the other is a C++/CLR.

C++/CLR project loads a DLL and exposes its functionality as a managed DLL to be used by C#.

When the application finishes, the DLL should be deleted. I have a suitable code in my code to free the library.

The last part of this process is to actually free the library and I have this code (This is C++ code)

[image]

As you can see there is a breakpoint and also an std::cout line.

If I comment out the std::cout line, then the breakpoint is not called.

If I let the std::cout active in the code, the breakpoint hits and it prints out.

I am building in Debug mode so I don't believe the code removed as part of optimization.
I cleaned the project and have the same issue.
I rebuild the project and have the same issue.

I am wondering why this is happening and can I be sure that the library is freed in this case?

## Edit 1

I think there is no code optimization (I am using MSVC 2019):

[image]

Comment: what is your compelation flags are? it look like compailer optimization

Comment: read the second answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-to-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c) on how to prevent code optimization

Comment: @yaodav Please see the updated question. I believe all optimizations are disabled. Is there anywhere else that I should look for optimization?

Comment: or use pragma or use volatile var, but if the compiler is optimize your code be sure that he is also deleting your library

Comment: @yaodav Can you please elaborate? How to use pragma?

Comment: like [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0") your code`

Comment: @yaodavThis is for GCC,but I am using Visual Studio for his project.

Comment: try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code?view=vs-2019) visual studio doc

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @WernerHenze I understand your point, In this case the actual code is not important, but the position of breakpoint and why it is not hit is important. If I copied the code, It doesn't give more information. I always copy and paste my code as I know that image of code is not sufficient for code debugging.