# How to prevent inlined class template from being deleted by compiler

Tags: c++

I have this class template defined in `test.hpp`:

```cpp
#pragma once

extern void Foo();

template <typename F>
class MyClass {
public:
  void Compute() {
    Foo();
  }
};
```

And a function `test()` instantiate `MyClass` in `test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "test.hpp"

void test() {
  MyClass<int> a;
  a.Compute();
}
```

If compiled with `clang++ test.cpp -S -emit-llvm`, `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<int>::Compute()` are kept in generated ll file.

```cpp
  6 %class.MyClass = type { i8 }
  7 ; Function Attrs: noinline optnone ssp uwtable
  8 define void @_Z4testv() #0 {
  9   %1 = alloca %class.MyClass, align 1
 10   call void @_ZN7MyClassIiE7ComputeEv(%class.MyClass* %1)
 11   ret void
 12 }
 13 ; Function Attrs: noinline optnone ssp uwtable
 14 define linkonce_odr void @_ZN7MyClassIiE7ComputeEv(%class.MyClass* %0) #0 align 2 {
 15   %2 = alloca %class.MyClass*, align 8
 16   store %class.MyClass* %0, %class.MyClass** %2, align 8
 17   %3 = load %class.MyClass*, %class.MyClass** %2, align 8
 18   call void @_Z3Foov()
 19   ret void
 20 }
```

But for O2 compilation, `MyClass<int>::Compute()` is inlined and deleted, together with the `MyClass<int>` definition. For some reason, I want them kept in the generated file, like in O0. So my question is that is there a way to keep them not deleted? I'd expect a simple attribute on the class or the member function.

----Edit----

The reason I want to keep the class is because I need to register it into a framework. That framework will find its 'Compute' method and call it on demand. I thought it may fail the framework if the class definition is deleted. But in my real senario, 'MyClass' needs to be derived from a base class provided by the framework, and 'Compute' is a virtual function that 'MyClass' needs to override. On registering this class, I must provide a builder which returns a pointer of base class, pointing to 'MyClass' (like `template <typename F> BaseClass *Builder() { return new MyClass<F>{}; }`. And with all these present, the compiler won't delete 'MyClass'. When I was asking this question, I was trying to implement this derived class as a template class in a header file, and thought it might be a little bit different than a regular class implemented in cpp file that the framework usually expect. It turns out not that special. So I guess my question is not a good question. Thanks for all the comments and answers, still help me a lot, thanks.

Comment: A C++ compiler is allowed to perform any optimization that has no observable effects. Your compiler has determined that performing this optimization has no observable effect, hence it is removed. What actual, real problem does this optimization create for you?

Comment: make it volatile

Comment: Can you explain why you need to to keep it? What problem do you try to solve with that? Depending on why you need that the correct answer might be different.

Comment: The reason I want to keep it is because I need to register the class `MyClass` (actually `MyClass<int>` into a framework, and that framework calls its `Compute()` function. So if they are deleted, I'm afraid the framework won't find them.

Comment: @Long Not enough context to tell, but maybe you are looking for [explicit template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used).

Comment: @dxiv Close to what I want. But in my case, the type parameter `F` in the template will be a lambda function given by user, which is not predictable..

Comment: @Long You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65860737/edit) the question to reflect what you actually mean to ask.

Answer (score 2):

according to [How to prevent gcc optimizing some statements in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-to-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c)

for **GCC**
You can use

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")

your code

#pragma GCC pop_options
```

or

```
 __attribute__((optimize("O0")))
```

for **CLANG**
use:

```
[[clang::optnone]]
```

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#id318

---

if your use this flags for generating ll file it will produce the correct code and you won't need to change the code:

```
-O2 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes -S -emit-llvm
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oe31nv