# PMU reports no L1 cache loads when working with 1-3 cache lines - where does the CPU access the data?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I run a dummy program that accesses an array of L1-cache-line sized data, to test how the cache architecture shows up in the miss rate etc metrics. Unexpectedly, when the program access only 1-3 lines, the Linux `perf` tool shows almost no L1 load events, as reported by the PMU counters. But the L1 loads jump to a large number when it accesses 4 lines. After that the number of loads increases linearly with the number of lines. There are <1% L1 misses, up to the point when the array of lines becomes larger than L1 cache size.

The same behavior is observed on AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G (Zen 2 "Renoir") and Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4116. In both cases, the cache line size is 64 bytes, the L1 cache size (per 1 core) is 32KB. The AMD L1 cache is 8-way. Originally, I thought there may be some change in performance metrics when the program accesses 8 lines, but no.

Does it mean that the memory subsystem of the CPU backend can work with up to 3 lines in its internal buffers or queues, without writing them to L1 cache and reading back? Is the number 3 related to the number of AGU units in the memory subsytem? I.e. each unit keeps 1 line in its internal memory, etc.

Roughly, the test program:

```
#define N_LINES 1
#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE 64

alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) uint64_t buffer [N_LINES][CACHE_LINE_SIZE / sizeof(uint64_t)];

static long long unsigned repeat    = 1000* 128 * 2 * 16 * 16 ;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// pin CPU
// warmup data, i.e. loop & write in buffer[i][0] = i

for (unsigned rep=0; rep<repeat; rep++) {
    for (unsigned i_line=0; i_block<N_LINES; i_line++) {
        // touch the first uint64 in the line
        buffer[i_line][0] += 1;
    }
}
}
```

The compilation & `perf` measurements:

```
g++ -g -O1 ./test_cache.cpp
sudo perf stat \
  -e task-clock,instructions,cycles,stalled-cycles-frontend,stalled-cycles-backend \
  -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-prefetches \
  -- ./a.out
```

E.g. L1 loads for 3 and 4 lines in the array:

```
            34,374      L1-dcache-loads                  #    1.006 M/sec                       (35.11%)
             2,460      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    7.16% of all L1-dcache accesses   (35.11%)

       260,407,342      L1-dcache-loads                  #    1.938 G/sec                       (17.86%)
             5,037      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    0.00% of all L1-dcache accesses   (17.86%)
```

Comment: If this was just Zen 2, I was thinking it might be https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41 - zero-latency store-to-load forwarding might be a special case for performance counters since no actual access to L1d cache happens.  Actually, that might also be the case for normal store-forwarding on Intel Skylake; it's a load but the data comes from the store buffer, not L1d cache.  (But L1d cache is still probed in parallel with snooping the store buffer.)

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't compile.  Missing `#include <stdint.h>` and a declaration of `i_block`.  Was that supposed to be `i_line`?

Comment: Your C source is too simple (and missing `volatile`); even at `-O1`, GCC just optimized away the memory increments for `N_LINES` = 1 to 3.  Look at the asm: there are just 3 `add reg, 1` instructions with 3 different registers.  Only with 4 or more iterations does `-O1` not fully unroll and optimize the four array elements you touch into registers.  https://godbolt.org/z/EzEP8v1Ej

Comment: [How can I prevent GCC optimizing some statements in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2219829) is another possible duplicate.  Anyway, declare `buffer` as an array of `volatile uint64_t`

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant it to be more like a pseudo-code example, to keep the question short. The actual program has a few more options, like having spacing between the accessed cache lines, using huge pages, and turning perf on and off inside the program. I will edit the question to make it an actual program code.

Comment: Regardless, optimizing the array elements into registers is very likely what's happening. With current GCC `-O1`, that happens for size 3 or less, but not with 4, exactly what you observe, and easily explains your perf results.  You can also check counts for `mem_inst_retired.all_loads` (which exists on Intel at least) to see how many total loads happened in the asm, if you don't want to just look at the hot loop asm manually.  Or just make the array `volatile` and see if that leads to the results you expected.

Comment: indeed! my bad. `g++ -Og` also gets it to the expected behavior. The number of loads and performance make sense.