# What is the advantage of "volatile" in this case?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, volatile

I have the following function implementation that checks for NULL pointer. This is a part of Linux driver, C code:

```
bool is_null_ponter(volatile void* ptr)
{
  return (NULL == ptr)? true : false;
}
```

What is the advantage of volatile in that case? Why not to put it in a register?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604569/what-kinds-of-optimizations-does-volatile-prevent-in-c/3604599#3604599, an answer to a similar (but not duplicate, IMHO) question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `volatile` helps that any pointer can be passed to the function without error or warning even if it is `volatile` qualified.

But this is bogus, the driver you see seems not to be written very professionally.

First, to be complete such a pointer should also be `const` qualified, only then it would capture really all pointers.

Then, there is no use case for such a function at all. In a `_Bool` context (here `!ptr`) pointers naturally lead to the correct answer, this is specified by the standard. Doing it differently as you see here is probably much frowned upon in the kernel community and I guess that this driver has not been reviewed properly.

Comment: I agree: the first thought that crossed my mind when I saw this was, "I'd like to go look at the revision history to see who put this little gem into the Linux repo."

Comment: I have a feeling this code was meant to be a pointer to a volatile variable (so the pointer should be deref'd every read), not a volatile pointer, which gets back to 'not to be written very professionally'