# Bypassing the Data cache in a Nios II Processor

Tags: c, caching, temporal, nios

I have the following C source files which need to have some code removed and some code added to bypass the data cache on the Nios_2_r2c processor. I have no clue how to do this.

#### File: switches.c

```
#include "system.h"
#include "pio_regs.h"
#include "bsu_macros.h"
#include "switches.h"

static struct pio_regs *SW = (struct pio_regs *)SWITCH_BASE;
static REGISTER SH_SW;

bits get_RUN ( void ) {
    SH_SW = SW->data;
    return getbit(SH_SW, 17);
}
```

#### File: ledr.c

```
#include "system.h"
#include "pio_regs.h"
#include "bsu_macros.h"
#include "ledr.h"

static struct pio_regs *LEDR = (struct pio_regs *)LEDR_BASE;
static REGISTER SH_LEDR;

void LEDR_Init ( void ) {
    SH_LEDR = 0;
    LEDR->data = 0;
}

void show_RUN ( bits RUN ) {
    SH_LEDR = putbit (SH_LEDR, RUN, 12);
    LEDR->data = SH_LEDR;
}
```

Got it with inline assembly using I/O read and writes:

#### File: switches.c

```
#include "system.h"
#include "pio_regs.h"
#include "bsu_macros.h"
#include "switches.h"

static struct pio_regs *SW = (struct pio_regs *)SWITCH_BASE;
static REGISTER SH_SW;

bits get_RUN ( void ) {
    //SH_SW = SW->data;
    __asm("ldwio %0, %1" : "=r"(SH_SW) : "m"(SW->data));
    return getbit(SH_SW, 17);
}
```

#### File: ledr.c

```
#include "system.h"
#include "pio_regs.h"
#include "bsu_macros.h"
#include "ledr.h" 

static struct pio_regs *LEDR = (struct pio_regs *)LEDR_BASE;
static REGISTER SH_LEDR;

void LEDR_Init ( void ) {
    SH_LEDR = 0;
    //LEDR->data = 0;
    __asm("stwio %0, %1" : "=r"(SH_LEDR) : "m"(SW->data));
}

void show_RUN ( bits RUN ) {
    SH_LEDR = putbit (SH_LEDR, RUN, 12);
    //LEDR->data = SH_LEDR;
    __asm("stwio %0, %1" : "=r"(SH_SW) : "m"(SW->data));
}
```

Comment: It might help to outline what resources you have looked at and how they aren't or are helping you...

Comment: Yikes, you appear to be the only person ever (on the internet) to ask this question.  Congratulations! BTW, I assume you have this book http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii5v1.pdf See page 2-14 for a description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks KevinD lol.

The resources I've looked at talk about some methods, but provide no examples. Like using the bit-31 method. I know that changing bit 31 (the MSB) will bypass the cache, but they never show an example of how to do this in C. Or using some macros which don't exist on this Nios because we aren't using HAL

Comment: You're probably stuck with Altera support - they have to have examples of how this is supposed to be done.  BTW, it seems all their example code is assembly, maybe a gcc group specific to this processor exists and can help with your query?

Comment: I solved it with inline assembly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-mno-cache-volatile` and declare the variable as `volatile`. In fact MMIOs that are achieved by reading/writing some registers **must** always be volatile.

> - `-mno-cache-volatile`
> - `-mcache-volatile`
>
>   Volatile memory access bypass the cache using the I/O variants of the load and store instructions. The default is not to bypass the cache.
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nios-II-Options.html

Another option is always bypass the cache by `-mbypass-cache`

See

- [Memory mapped registers in C/C++](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_mapped_registers_in_C/C++)
- [Use of volatile for registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49039977/995714)
- [Why is volatile needed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246127/995714)
- [Managing cache with memory mapped I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38366109/995714)
- [Cache bypass in NIOS II](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00003yyIyuSAE/cache-bypass?language=en_US)