# Managing cache with memory mapped I/O

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, operating-system, memory-barriers

I have a question regarding memory mapped io.
Suppose, there is a memory mapped IO peripheral whose value is being read by CPU. Once read, the value is stored in cache. But the value in memory has been updated by external IO peripheral.
In such cases how will CPU determine cache has been invalidated and what could be the workaround for such case?

Answer (score 6):

That's strongly platform dependent. And actually, there are two different cases.

**Case #1.** Memory-mapped peripheral. This means that access to some range of physical memory addresses is routed to peripheral device. There is no actual RAM involved. To control caching, x86, for example, has MTRR ("memory type range registers") and PAT ("page attribute tables"). They allow to set caching mode on particular range of physical memory. Under normal circumstances, range of memory mapped to RAM is *write-back cacheable*, while range of memory mapped to periphery devices is *uncacheable*. Different caching policies are described in [Intel's system programming guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf), 11.3 "Methods of caching available". So, when you issue read or write request to memory mapped peripheral, CPU cache is bypassed, and request goes directly to the device.

**Case #2.** DMA. It allows peripheral devices to access RAM asynchronously. In this case, DMA controller is no different from any CPU and equally participates in cache coherency protocol. Write request from periphery is seen by caches of other CPUs, and cache lines are either invalidated or are updated with new data. Read request also is seen by caches of other CPUs and data is returned from cache rather than from main RAM. (This is only an example: actual implementation is platform dependent. For example, SoC typically do not guarantee strong cache coherency peripheral <-> CPU.)

In both cases, the problem of caching also exists at compiler level: complier may cache data values in registers. That's why programming languages has some means of prohibiting such optimization: for example, `volatile` keyword in C.