# Use of volatile for registers

Tags: c, volatile

I am wondering how efficient / is working the volatile declaration. In the following code:

```
volatile char var1 = * (volatile char *) 0x2000000;
printf("%d \n", var1 + 1);
```

It means that every time I am using the variable "var", it will be loaded from the address memory 0x2000000, but is the volatile cast of a fixed address necessary, or is it only to fit the type of var1?

Does this means that every time "var1" is read, it is read from memory, and not from a potential cached value? So in this code, we access two times the address 0x2000000?

Comment: volatile means just that.  It tells the compiler that it can assume nothing about the location and that it must reload each time.  Useful for I/O mapped registers (for example) where the compiler has no idea on what is actually there.

Comment: But the cast should be unnecessary in my opinion

Comment: The volatile on `var1` seems not needed.  Generally the pointer as volatile is enough for my example.

Comment: If worried, look at the assembly output.  It will tell all...

Comment: You're mistaken about the declaration, though. You've declared a variable var1 *on the stack*, and initialized it from 0x2000000. But subsequent reads of that variable will come from its stack address.

Comment: Curious if that `var1` on stack would reload the stack value each time instead of placing it into a register.  That would be interesting and not what seems intended from the original code where it seems they want the address lookup each time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is the volatile cast of a fixed address necessary, (?)

Yes, consider the below.  Compiler could reason `(char *) 0x2000000` was read once, no need to read again for `volatile char var2 = * (char *) 0x2000000;`.  Just use the value that was read before and saved away in some internal memory/register.  Targets `var1/var2`, being `volatile`, do  not affect the right-hand-side of the assignment.

```
volatile char var1 = * (char *) 0x2000000;
printf("%d \n", var1);
volatile char var2 = * (char *) 0x2000000;
printf("%d \n", var2);
```

---

The `volatile` with `volatile char var1` is not needed.  Defining a pointer to `volatile` data is likely more in line with coding goals.

```
volatile char *ptr1 = (volatile char *) 0x2000000;
printf("%d \n", *ptr1);
printf("%d \n", *ptr1);  // A 2nd read of `(volatile char *) 0x2000000` occurs.
```

Comment: Ok I think I got it, you mean (and the others people commenting too) that the "volatile char var1" implies that I will read the value from the stack every time I read "var1". The value cached is dropped. But the real value is stored only once on the stack, so the value fetched by "var1" is only valable once.

Comment: @Jone Not quite.   `volatile char var1 = 5; printf("%d \n", var1); printf("%d \n", var1); printf("%d \n", var1);` would require code to read `var1` 3-times and not optimize code to do `printf("5\n5\n5\n");`.  But this has nothing to do with volatile data pointed to by `(volatile char *) 0x2000000`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written it, `volatile char var1 = * (volatile char *) 0x2000000;`, this says to create an object named `var1` (allocated at a place the C implementation chooses) and to initialize it to a value read from 0x2000000. Every time `var1` is read, the copied value will be read from the place the implementation allocated. It will not be reread from 0x2000000.

You may want `volatile char *var1 = (volatile char *) 0x2000000;`. This defines `var1` to be a pointer to 0x2000000. With this definition, every time `*var1` is used, the value will be read from 0x2000000.