# Volatile in C, How does it work internally

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, cpu-registers

Just wondering how exactly volatile keyword works internally.

Tried with GCC and Turbo C(DOS based) both cases it behaves in different manners.

```
volatile int iData;
iData = 5;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ++iData, iData++, iData++, ++iData, iData, iData++);
```

does the output depend upon printf function data passing or compiler based?

Thank you
Cheers !!

Comment: The output can depend on anything you want because your program invokes undefined behavior. And it does so irrespective of `iData` being or not being `volatile`. This is a duplicate question.

Comment: look up `ISO/IEC TR3` standard draft section `6.7.3.6`. [Link](www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).the section is not difficult to understand

Comment: Don't try with Turbo C, it doesn't follow any version of the C standard. Furthermore your example is nonsense and relies on both undefined and unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behaviour* by modifying `iData` more than once in the same statement. Since the behaviour is undefined, different compilers can do different things for it and neither of them is wrong. So you really don't want undefined behaviour in your code.

See [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc) for more details.

Note: the odd behaviour in your code has nothing to do with the `volatile` keyword. For more information on `volatile` see [Why is volatile needed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c)

Comment: Thank you Scott.
I would like to know how exactly volatile works ?

Comment: @Planet: Then post a new question. The code in your question has nothing to do with how `volatile` works because the whole program has undefined behavior due to modifying an object multiple times without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: @Planet I added a link at the bottom that should explain `volatile`.