# Is it neccessary to use volatile keyword when directly accessing physical address?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, bootloader

In a boot loader code i found that, they are using volatile keyword when accessing physical address. Is it necessary to use volatile keyword even we are accessing physical memory address?

Comment: "Is it necessary to use volatile keyword even we are accessing physical memory address? " -- That's the most common purpose for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is volatile needed in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "volatile" whenever the data can change, without the compiler being able to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is to disable compiler optimization and to fetch current value only.Meaning of *current value* only is system will fetch current value even if the value from the same object is used in previous instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any means that the contents at this physical address can be changed without the compiler knowing about it (when the compiler is only inspecting your local code)? If yes, then you must use the volatile keyword -- otherwise you cannot be certain the compiler will actually read the memory.

For physical addresses which are, for example, device registers, you do want to use the volatile keyword.