# Pointer to specific address in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Assuming that the address 0xCF800000 is free for writing:

A) Is it correct to say that both codes produce the same result?

```
int main( void )
{
  volatile unsigned long *pt = (volatile unsigned long *) 0xCF800000;
  *pt = 0x00000000;
}
```

and

```
int main( void )
{
  (*(volatile unsigned long *) 0xCF800000) = 0x00000000;
}
```

B) On the first code, the statement " (volatile unsigned long *) " before 0xCF800000 is necessary or is a redundancy?

C) On the first code there is a variable pt, that has its own address, where I put some content: 0xCF800000. By dereferencing pt, the computer will take the contents of pt (0xCF800000), 'locate' that address, and assign 0x00000000 to that location. On the second code, I can not understand exactly how it works, since there is no variable. Looks like the information 0xCF800000 is "nowhere".

Comment: Note: I don't think the `volatile` is needed. The object at the given adress is only referenced once, so it has to be retrieved anyway.

Comment: are these questions from a job interview?

Comment: ahahaha. No.. Why?
@wildplasser indeed! The volatile is there just because this doubt appear during a class about GPIO

Comment: BTW: you dont need `*pt = 0x00000000;` because `*pt = 0;` will do the same. Smells like cargo cult... Extra: the constant `0xCF800000` might be signed without a cast or `u` postfix.

Comment: A) yes. B) necessary. C) you need to look at the assembly to understand how the compiler implements your code. Otherwise, you just have to trust random strangers on the internet.

Comment: These are both the same in Standard C

Answer (score 0):

you made casting to (unsigned long *), what means for compiler treat this value like a pointer to unsigned long and do not complain.
But as @user3386109 said, it is always good to check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You actually posted 3 questions, each of which requires a separate answer, so:
Regarding A: 
Depends on the value you write to this memory location (sic!). 
You are on the safe side as long if this is zero, or many small values. **But** if the most significant bit of this value is `1`, **and** if it will be sign-extended for some reasons (depending among others on your cast, see my answer to your question B) – then you will get into problems.

To avoid these problems you should suffix the value with an `u` to indicate it is unsigned (again, this is unimportant if it is zero).
So if your constant value to store would be e.g. 0xA0000000 (note the most-significant bit is a `1`!) you should write it as:  0xA0000000u instead.
*BTW: 0x00000000 is just 0, you do not need to write that much zeroes in it, but I understand that this is part of a longer code and you want to be coherent with your other, longer values*

Answer (score 0):

You actually posted 3 questions, each of which requires a separate answer, so:
Regarding B: 
The code: `(volatile unsigned long *)` is a cast. Its necessity depends on the size of the integer type used for storing addresses in your compiler (this type should be `typedef`’ed to `size_t` by your compiler).  
In short:
**you are ok without a cast** here as long as this literal constant has as many bits as addresses used by your compiler, i.e. If your compiler uses 32-bit addresses. 
**you need a cast** if your compiler uses more than 32 bits for addresses. This plays its role, because you dereference this literal constant as an address (using unary `*` operator). In such case bear in mind that literal constant like 0xCF800000 will be extended from its current 32 bits. Because the highest bit of `0xCF800000` is a ‘1’ so this will result in so called *signed extension* (the leading ‘1’ will be copied to the most significant bits), so you will get a different memory address than the one you want !

Another question is, if you need the `volatile` in your cast. You only need `volatile` in some specific cases, namely when the memory location can be used by some **other code/device in the same time**. See [Why is volatile needed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c%20for%20details)
 .

Answer (score 0):

> On the second code, I can not understand exactly how it works, since there is no variable. Looks like the information 0xCF800000 is "nowhere".

To address your questions C): It is a number literal which is later casted to pointer by you. In most computer systems, a literal as long as (0xCF800000) will be compiled into an immediate, and dereferencing an pointer value is a memory-read instruction.

Let's look at what your second example code compiled into on x86:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 11
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $3481272320, %ecx       ## imm = 0xCF800000
    movl    %ecx, %edx
    movq    $0, (%rdx)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

In particular, the three lines

```
    movl    $3481272320, %ecx       ## imm = 0xCF800000
    movl    %ecx, %edx
    movq    $0, (%rdx)
```

Reads a constant number value into a register, then write 0 to the memory whose address is same as that register value.

Answer (score 0):

You actually posted 3 questions, each of which requires a separate answer, so:
Regarding C: 
You ask  how:
`(*(volatile unsigned long *) 0xCF800000) = 0x00000000;`
works, but I am sure you know this, you just do not know that you happen to know. ;-)
The above instruction is just an assignment. For an assignment to work, both its left-hand-side and its right-hand-side have to be evaluated first.
The variety of valid expressions on the right-hand side is tremendous. The left-hand-side has many limitations, as it must evaluate to a memory location. An example of such memory location is `int a`, so you can write: `a =  0x00000000`.
Another memory location is `int tab[N]` so you can write:  `tab[0]= 0x00000000`;
Yet another example is `int* p` , so you can write:  `*p =  0x00000000`.
As you see we came very close to your question: if you agree that `*p`, which expands to a memory address, can be used on the left-hand-side of an assignment instruction, why should not a constant?
A constant is perfectly ok here, so you can even write very simply:
`*(int*)0 = 5`
 which means: take the value zero, then cast it to (=treat it like) an address with `int*`, then dereference this address with the unary `*` operator, then assign the integer value of 5 to this memory location.
*Of course my last example assumes that the memory location 0 is writable. Also all my two previous answers in this thread, regarding bit extensions, should be applied here, I am now skipping casting for clarity only*