# how to access a particular register of a microcontroller using pointers

Tags: c, embedded

I wanted to know how to access a particular register in a microcontroller  having mapped at a particular fixed address. I googled about this issue and I found the following:

```
#define WDTCTL     (*((volatile unsigned short *)0x0120))
#define P1DIR (*((volatile unsigned char *)0x0022))
```

This method of works absolutely fine but I do not understand how it works.

I  will be glad if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: I saw a similar question several times already, but cannot find the dupe.

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this question to be found on SO.

Comment: Hey can u guys provide the links to previously asked identical questions

Answer (score 1):

> define WDTCTL     (*((volatile unsigned short *)0x0120))

This means that `WDTCTL` register is at the address `0x0120`. 
`(volatile unsigned short *)` will typecast that into a short pointer. 
Then `(*((volatile unsigned short *)0x0120))` will give the value at that pointer location.

The reason to use `volatile` here is that for microcontroller addresses, the value can change at any time independently of the C code. The `volatile` keyword disallows compiler optimizations around this register.

For more information see [Why is volatile needed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I have a question can I do the above in this way, "volatile unsigned short *WDTCTL " , "WDTCTL=0×0120" and then dereference it "*WDTCTL = 0×01" and write whatever I want. Pls reply

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that. However, in your case you are assigning a pointer variable `WDCTL` which will take some memory. Also you will have to do it for all the registers of the microcontroller, which might take too much memory.