# C - volatile qualifier while lock is held

Tags: c, concurrency, locking, volatile, nonatomic

Do I need the volatile qualifier for variables only accessed while a lock is held?  In this code, could removing the volatile qualifier from `n` possibly change the behavior when `concurrent_foo` is executed concurrently.

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#error __sync_lock builtins are only available with GCC
#endif

volatile int n = 0;
static volatile int lock = 0;

void concurrent_foo () {
    while (__sync_lock_test_and_set (&lock, 1));
    // Non-atomic operation, protected by spinlock above.
    int x = n % 2 + 1;
    n = n + x;
    __sync_lock_release (&lock);
}
```

I understand that the volatile qualifier instructs the compiler not to optimize memory accesses to a variable.  I also understand that the __sync_lock builtins issue a (full?) memory barrier, which memory accesses should not cross.  However, it would be safe in this example code to fetch `n`, cache it in a register, compute the new value, and then write it back to `n`.

Compiling with GCC to i686 source using `-O3` reveals that two memory fetches are made, unessesarily:

```
concurrent_foo:
        movl        $1, %edx
.L2:
        movl        %edx, %eax
        xchgl        lock, %eax
        testl        %eax, %eax
        jne        .L2
        movl        n, %eax
        movl        n, %edx
        movl        %eax, %ecx
        shrl        $31, %ecx
        addl        %ecx, %eax
        andl        $1, %eax
        subl        %ecx, %eax
        leal        1(%edx,%eax), %eax
        movl        %eax, n
        movl        $0, lock
        ret
```

Without the volatile qualifier I get subtly different code, where `n` is fetched just once:

```
concurrent_foo:
        movl        $1, %edx
.L2:
        movl        %edx, %eax
        xchgl        lock, %eax
        testl        %eax, %eax
        jne        .L2
        movl        n, %edx
        movl        %edx, %ecx
        shrl        $31, %ecx
        leal        (%edx,%ecx), %eax
        andl        $1, %eax
        subl        %ecx, %eax
        leal        1(%edx,%eax), %eax
        movl        %eax, n
        movl        $0, lock
        ret
```

In both circumstances, memory accesses to `n` occur while the lock is held, and thus should be "correct".  However, I am unsure if I am really guaranteed that. The volatile qualifier is preventing a performance optimization that I would like and would not affect the outcome of the operation (at no point would `n` be even).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308849/1491895

Comment: 1) `volatile does not guarantee atomicity. 2) Don't use compiler extensions if there are stadard featrures. Use `stdatomic.h`. The `__sync_XXX` builtins are legacies and should not be used for new code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Olaf, but unfortunately for me stdatomic.h is only as portable as the __sync builtins because I'm writing freestanding code.