# How to perform write back of dirty L1-L2 cache lines in ARMv8

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module, armv8

I'm looking for a way to flush the L1-L2 cache using a kernel module.
Is there a way to completely flush the whole cluster cache (4 core configuration) or even better, write back the dirty cache lines into main memory?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird that you want to flush your caches from a kernel module. That should be done by the core-kernel part and as a driver you should not have to worry about that.

Is there any specific reason you need to do that in a driver?

Comment: I want to achieve data coherency between the SoC and external devices. So if data in an allocated page are modified by X, i want to make sure that the changes will be visible to Y, which is outside the cache coherency of X

Comment: so why not just use the `volatile` keyword [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c?) ? It prevents data to be written to cache in first place

Comment: @jonnyx volatile keyword tells the compiler to reread data value instead of assuming that it has stayed the same. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a look at 3.9 of "Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager" [1] from Mel Gorman. I think what you are looking for is flush_cache_page(...)

[1] https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/

Comment: Nice one, but I cannot find an implementation for the Arm64 architecture, only for the older arm. Thanks a lot though. Things get complicated as there is a more sophisticated L2 cache controller present in Armv8

Comment: Fair enough, but there are other methods implemented for arm64, did you had a look at __flush_dcache_area(kaddr, size)?

Comment: Yes I did, from what i read, it flushes a page, or an area, from L1 cache, and sends it to the L2 cache.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that it is actually different the way that the caches are flushed in different architectures. Nevertheless, I didn't find an implementation that works. BUT, what I did was to find the Page table entry (PTE) of the particular page that I want to flush, and changed the memory attributes to Non-Cacheable. Then, the data went directly to the DRAM. (ARMv8)
Cheers