# Motor runs despite not calling it

Tags: c, mplab, pwm

currently doing a project with a board with several routines:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define SW1 PORTBbits.RB4
#define SW2 PORTBbits.RB5
#define PB3 PORTCbits.RC3 //for testing
#define PB2 PORTDbits.RD1
#define PB7 PORTCbits.RC7
#define PB8 PORTCbits.RC6
#define MOTOR PORTDbits.RD0

void initSysPins(void);
void ReadLight(void);
void ReadTemperature(void);
void ReadSoilMoisture(void);
void MessageDoze(void);
void MessageSleep(void);
void lcdClear(void);
void initLCD(void);
void initSysInt(void);
void initSysTimer(void);
void pwrMgmt(void);
void initPWM(void);
unsigned char detPB3(void); //for testing
unsigned char detPB2(void);
unsigned char detPB7(void);
unsigned char detPB8(void);

 
void main(void) {
    
    initSysInt();
    initSysPins();
    initSysTimer();
    CPUDOZE = 0;
    
    
    while(TRUE){
        if(SW1 == 1 && SW2 == 0){
            ReadTemperature();
        }
        else if (SW1 == 0 && SW2 == 1){
            ReadLight();
        }
        else if (SW1 == 1 && SW2 == 1){
            ReadSoilMoisture();
        }
        else {
            lcdClear();
        }
        pwrMgmt();
        //pwrMgmt1();
    }
}

void pwrMgmt(void){
    if(PB2 == 0){
        lcdClear();
        ROI = 1;
        MessageSleep();
        SLEEP();
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    
    else if(PB7 == 0){
        lcdClear();
        MessageDoze();
        DOZEN= 1;
        ROI = 1;
    } 
}

unsigned char detPB3(void)
{
    unsigned char detect = 0; //initial status, sw1 not pressed
    if(PB3 == 0)             //if sw1 is pressed
    {
        __delay_ms(20);     // 20ms delay to skip contact bounce
        if(PB3 == 0)        //if still pressed
        {
            detect = 1;     //confirm sw1 is pressed n set detect
            while(PB3 == 0);//wait for sw1 to be released
        }
    }
    return detect;
}

unsigned char detPB2(void)
{
    unsigned char detect = 0; //initial status, sw1 not pressed
    if(PB2 == 0)             //if sw1 is pressed
    {
        __delay_ms(20);     // 20ms delay to skip contact bounce
        if(PB2 == 0)        //if still pressed
        {
            detect = 1;     //confirm sw1 is pressed n set detect
            while(PB2 == 0);//wait for sw1 to be released
        }
    }
    return detect;
}

unsigned char detPB7(void)
{
    unsigned char detect = 0; //initial status, sw1 not pressed
    if(PB7 == 0)             //if sw1 is pressed
    {
        __delay_ms(20);     // 20ms delay to skip contact bounce
        if(PB7 == 0)        //if still pressed
        {
            detect = 1;     //confirm sw1 is pressed n set detect
            while(PB7 == 0);//wait for sw1 to be released
        }
    }
    return detect;
}

unsigned char detPB8(void)
{
    unsigned char detect = 0; //initial status, sw1 not pressed
    if(PB8 == 0)             //if sw1 is pressed
    {
        __delay_ms(20);     // 20ms delay to skip contact bounce
        if(PB8 == 0)        //if still pressed
        {
            detect = 1;     //confirm sw1 is pressed n set detect
            while(PB8 == 0);//wait for sw1 to be released
        }
    }
    return detect;
}
```

The only problem is that my DC motor still runs on its own despite only being called inside my soil moisture function. the other functions just use LCD and LED and work fine. I've tried working around this by putting `MOTOR = 0;` inside my main but that doesn't do anything.

EDIT: Works on its own before integration with the rest of my codes.

ReadSoilMoisture():

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"
#define lcd_Clear 0b00000001  
#define LCD_DATA PORTD
#define LCD_RS PORTEbits.RE1    //RS signal for LCD
#define LCD_E PORTEbits.RE0 // E signal for LCD
#define MOTOR PORTDbits.RD0


void initSysPins(void);
void lcdWriteData(char);
void lcdWriteCtrl(char);
void lcdWriteMessage(char message[], unsigned char row);
void lcdSetPos(unsigned char row, unsigned char col);
void initPWM(void);

//void Message(void);
void Message1(void);
void Message2(void);
void Message(void);

void initLCD(void);
void initADC(void);
unsigned int readPot1(void);

void ReadSoilMoisture(void) {
    
    unsigned int raw;
    unsigned char pwmCycle = 0;
    // float fresult;
    // char res[20];
    
    initLCD();
    initSysPins();
    initPWM();
    initADC();
    
    
    PWM6CONbits.EN = 1;
   // raw = readPot1();
    
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<=40; i++) {
         raw = readPot1(); 
         if (raw == 0 && raw <= 10)
            {
                PORTA = 0x00;
            }
         else if (raw == 11 && raw <=100)
            {
                PORTA = 0b00001001; //RED
                MOTOR = 1;
                pwmCycle = 4000;
                __delay_ms(5000);

                PWM6DCH = pwmCycle >> 2;
                PWM6DCL = (pwmCycle % 4)<< 6;  
                
                Message();
                __delay_ms(3000);
                lcdWriteCtrl(0b00000001); // Clear display & home position 
            }
         else if (raw == 101 && raw <= 1000) 
            {
                PORTA = 0b00010010; //YELLOW
                MOTOR = 1;
                pwmCycle = 1500;
                __delay_ms(3000);

                PWM6DCH = pwmCycle >> 2;
                PWM6DCL = (pwmCycle % 4)<< 6;  

                Message1();
                __delay_ms(3000);
                lcdWriteCtrl(0b00000001); // Clear display & home position
            }
         else if (raw == 1001 && raw <= 1023)
            {
                PORTA = 0b00100100; //GREEN
                MOTOR = 1;
                pwmCycle = 900;
                __delay_ms(800);

                PWM6DCH = pwmCycle >> 2;
                PWM6DCL = (pwmCycle % 4)<< 6;  
 
                Message2();
                __delay_ms(3000);
                lcdWriteCtrl(0b00000001); // Clear display & home position
            }
        }
}   


void Message(void){
    char message[] = "Soil Moisture";
    char message1[] = "Is 55%";
    unsigned char i;
    lcdSetPos(1,1); // Set DD RAM pos to row 1, col 3
        for(i = 0; message[i] != 0; i++) {
        lcdWriteData(message[i]); // Display one character
        }
        lcdSetPos(2,1); // Set DD RAM pos to row 2, col 1
        for(i = 0; message1[i] != 0; i++) {
           lcdWriteData(message1[i]); // Display one character
        }
}

void Message1(void){
    char message[] = "Soil Moisture";
    char message1[] = "Is 75%";
    unsigned char i;
    lcdSetPos(1,1); // Set DD RAM pos to row 1, col 3
        for(i = 0; message[i] != 0; i++) {
        lcdWriteData(message[i]); // Display one character
        }
        lcdSetPos(2,1); // Set DD RAM pos to row 2, col 1
        for(i = 0; message1[i] != 0; i++) {
           lcdWriteData(message1[i]); // Display one character
        }
}

void Message2(void){
    char message[] = "Soil Moisture";
    char message1[] = "Is 95%";
    unsigned char i;
    lcdSetPos(1,1); // Set DD RAM pos to row 1, col 3
        for(i = 0; message[i] != 0; i++) {
        lcdWriteData(message[i]); // Display one character
        }
        lcdSetPos(2,1); // Set DD RAM pos to row 2, col 1
        for(i = 0; message1[i] != 0; i++) {
           lcdWriteData(message1[i]); // Display one character
        }
}

void initPWM(void)
{
    CCPTMRS1 = PORTDbits.RD0;
    PWM6CON = 0b00000000;
    T2PR = 249;
    PWM6DCH = 0b01111101;
    PWM6DCL = 0b00000000;
    T2CON = 0b11110000; 
    T2CLKCON = 0b00000001;
    RA2PPS = 0x0E;
}
```

Any guess as to what I can do?

Comment: all the expressions in those `if` statements are looking suspicious. e.g `if (raw == 0 && raw <= 10)` . The first part is redundant.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu so it should be just `if (raw <= 10)` ?

Comment: If the motor runs regardless of what you set it to, are you sure it is connected to the correct pin? If the motor is connected via a relay, does it run when the relay input is disconnected - which would suggest a faulty relay (e.g. contacts shorted due to no flyback diode)?

Comment: @BorisLimJunXian yes just `if (raw <= 10)` is enough. Also make sure that `PORTDbits.RD0` is `volatile`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Pins are properly connected, even checked initSysPins config too. It could be the board being shorted as it's a used one provided by the school (which has numerous components already faulty and non-functioning).

Thing is though, the moisture codes on their own prior to integration were working fine.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu wdym by `vollatie`?

Comment: @BorisLimJunXian check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu I got `error: unknown type name 'PORTDbits'; did you mean 'PORTDbits_t'?` when I did `volatile MOTOR = 0;`

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu How do I make `PORTDbits.RD0` a volatile?

Comment: Check where the `PORTDbits` is defined? You should see a volatile keyword there like: `volatile <something> PORTDbits;`. If not, you should add.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu not quite sure what <something> is, I tried direct `volatile PORTDbits` but that didn't work

Comment: Find where PORTDbits is defined.