Is volatile needed with how smart compilers are these days?
Compilers are getting smarter and smarter these days. So, is volatile needed?
Compilers are smart enough to ask if we still need volatile ?
I tried many scenarios and it seemed like the compiler would do the optimizations correctly.
If your answer is NO, please give me some counterexamples, I am a C language novice.
For a global variable, I only find one case that compiler doesn't use memory value, as follow. Can you provide other examples?
int flag = 0;
while(flag == 0);


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c listed examples around hardware register, as smart as the compiler is it still can't (and shouldn't) decide that without the programmer's explicit input.

Compilers can't determine what variables are actually mapped to memory mapped peripheral registers. That is indicated to the compiler by specifying volatile. How smart the compiler is, isn't relevant. It is absolutely required. Admittedly, this is mostly an issue for embedded development, so may not be apparent if you aren't doing that kind of work.

is volatile needed? It is the other way round. Compilers have been too smart, so we need volatile to make them dumb again.

Also volatile is often needed to deal with the increasingly frequent compiler bugs. Compilers are not just getting smarter, they are getting exponentially buggier too.

The smarter compilers are, the more important it is to use volatile where it's needed, to stop compilers from optimizing in ways you don't want.  Or it would be better to say that it's always critically important to use volatile where necessary, but the chance of Bad Things actually happening in practice is higher with smarter compilers if you miss any cases that need it.

In a Linux kernel context specifically, see Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler? for how why Linux's READ_ONCE / WRITE_ONCE macros are important for lock-free atomics.  Concurrent read+write from separate threads is undefined behaviour in ISO C so aggressive optimizations are allowed for normal code that doesn't use volatile.  GNU C plus the underlying hardware defines the behaviour of volatile enough to get meaningful behaviour.
(See also MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop - most code shouldn't actually use volatile for multithreading or interrupts.  Use lock-free types from stdatomic.h like _Atomic int.)

Or a trivial example like writing to an MMIO register in a device driver:
static volatile uint32_t *const DEVICE_REGISTER = (void*)0x100000;
void write_two_things(){
    *DEVICE_REGISTER = 0x1111;
    *DEVICE_REGISTER = 0x2222;
}

Without volatile, the first store would be optimized away so the PCI device would never see it.  With plain variables, only the final value matters, so stores that get overwritten before anything could read them (without UB) might as well not have been done in the first place.  This is called dead store elimination.
See it for yourself on Godbolt, compiling to x86-64 asm with GCC -O2 , plus with an alternate version not using volatile.
write_two_things:
        mov     DWORD PTR ds:1048576, 4369     # 0x1111
        mov     DWORD PTR ds:1048576, 8738     # 0x2222
        ret
write_two_things_buggy:
        # first store was optimized away as being dead
        mov     DWORD PTR ds:2097152, 8738     # 0x2222
        ret


(When I wrote this answer, the question tags included [linux][assembly], hence my choice of examples.)

As an aside, even with volatile, the programmer needs to consider possible reordering of posted writes at the bus level. For example, if your DEVICE_REGISTER example was pointing to PCI MMIO, and was writing DEVICE_REGISTER[1] = 0x2222; DEVICE_REGISTER[0] = 0x1111; it is possible that DEVICE_REGISTER[0] could be physically written before DEVICE_REGISTER[1].

Peter, is Ian's example plausible? Is this the memory controller as I imagine the bus wouldn't do this. But, what about PCIe and transaction replay? And, is this confined to the PCI MMIO or is any memory mapped device affected? What is the remedy? Assuming area is mapped write-through (or uncached), do we need cpuid, mfence, sfence, ???

@CraigEstey: I haven't written device drivers, you should have tagged @Ian.  x86 UnCacheable memory regions are strongly ordered (unlike WC), I think not even StoreLoad being allowed inside the CPU core.  But if memory reordering is allowed somewhere else, then maybe you'd need sfence or mfence? IDK.  PCIe ordering rules and x86, how are they compatible? looks relevant, which I think is saying the bus itself shouldn't reorder posted writes, only devices can if that doesn't cause problems.  So probably no extra instructions needed on UC memory.

@PeterCordes In the book csapp 3e，it is said that:
“G4. Declare global variables with volatile. Consider a handler and main rou
tine that share a global variable g. The handler updates g, and mainpe-
riodically reads g. To an optimizing compiler, it would appear thatthe
value of g never changes in main, and thus it would be safe touse a copy
of g that is cached in a register to satisfy every reference to g. Intlis case,
the main function would never see the updated values from thhe handler.“
Is this rule reasonable now ? I didn't reproduce it.

@DaWang: In the rare case that you have a global variable modified by a signal handler or interrupt handler, yes, CS:APP is correct.  My answer on MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop explains in detail exactly why a compiler is allowed to hoist a load out of a a read loop if you don't declare the variable atomic_int or volatile sig_atomic_t or something.  (I already linked from this answer.)  You should not make all global variables volatile, you want optimizations like this in most cases.
