# Store ordering for larger-than-native-size type - C spec

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, volatile

Suppose you have a pointer to a larger-than-native-type integer, what do recent C specs say regarding the store ordering? E.g.:

```
volatile uint64_t *test = (volatile uint64_t *)(addr);
*test = 0;
```

On a 32-bit architecture this will compile to two stores, does the C spec say anything about which store will be first (addr or addr+4)? Or is it implementation defined?

Comment: This is a complex topic, but TL;DR: concurrent read/write or write/write access to shared storage without synchronisation is not defined.  If you need that, use atomics (volatile neither make variables atomic nor implies memory ordering! [unless on MSVC]), fences, locks, or other synchronisation facilities.

Comment: Now if you were to mark the variable as atomic, e.g. `_Atomic uint64_t`, then the implementation has to guarantee atomic semantics, though possibly by using a hidden lock somewhere.  Read the C standard (C11 or newer) for details.

Comment: Note that “larger-than-native-size” is a red herring.  There is no guarantee that writes to any non-atomic types happen in one store, with the sole exception of writes to variables of type `sig_atomic_t`, but for that type, the property is mainly guaranteed with respect to signal handlers.

Comment: It would be data-race UB to observe it from another thread within the C program.  The ISO C standard doesn't say anything about the internal details of a volatile access, so it's all up to an implementation. (*[What Rules does compiler have to follow when dealing with volatile memory locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4137115)*). If you have two adjacent MMIO registers and order matters, better use two separate `volatile uint32_t` accesses.  Real implementation probably do have a standard order, but it's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Now finally, note that many 32 bit architectures do in fact support 64 bit stores, so you're not even guaranteed two get two separate stores for a 64 bit variable on 32 bit architectures.

Comment: @fuz: Note that the guarantees only apply to `volatile sig_atomic_t`; plain `sig_atomic_t` is usually just `int`. Some compilers (like GCC and clang) treat `volatile` as a request for doing the access with a single instruction if possible if it's possible without jumping through hoops (like SSE2), making `volatile` usable for hand-rolled atomics in the Linux kernel with those compilers with other T. (*[Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71866535)*) But of course that isn't

Comment: *does the C spec say anything about which store will be first (addr or addr+4)?* On what basis do you assume it's two stores and not something like one byte from `addr` then four bytes from `addr + 1` then three bytes from `addr + 5`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: On what basis?  They appear to be talking about behaviour of existing real-world compilers like GCC and Clang where it does indeed compile to two 32-bit stores, or sometimes a store-pair on some ISAs that have such an instruction.  (https://godbolt.org/z/s9fq7PEd9).  That's of course not guaranteed by the ISO C standard, but it's not wrong to say that's what happens.  Compilers can't store bytes separately for `volatile sig_atomic_t`, which usually means not for `volatile int`, but yes in theory a Deathstation 9000 could for any other type.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard says nothing of the store order. It *likely* happens in the order of addressing, meaning that the data at the lowest address *likely* gets copied first (MS bytes on big endian, LS bytes on little endian). Likely (but not guaranteed) since copying in the order of addresses is what makes most sense on most ISA, particularly those with data cache.

---

Somewhat related:

What the C standard (5.1.2.3) does guarantee is that the whole 64 bits will get copied in between the two sequence points here:

```
... ;      // the semi colon is a sequence point
*test = 0; // the semi colon is a sequence point
```

No atomicity is guaranteed since `_Atomic` qualifiers weren't used. So the access may get interrupted halfways by a context switch to another thread or process - the access isn't guaranteed to be thread-safe.

5.1.2.3 isn't the best part of the standard, but if you read it literally then it also says that instruction reordering cannot happen across a `volatile` object, essentially making it act as a memory barrier.

However, another "language lawyer" aspect is that the C standard has always been broken since C90, speaking of `volatile` objects rather than a `volatile` lvalue access. In your code here, the pointed-at data is not necessarily a `volatile` object, maybe only the pointer is. Since the compiler might not know what's stored at the address you cast the pointer from, or what "effective type" and qualifiers that object got. This language "bug" is going to be fixed in the upcoming C23 standard that defines and uses the term *volatile access* instead.

Answer (score 0):

> what do recent C specs say regarding the store ordering?

The endian is implementation defined.

> does the C spec say anything about which store will be first (addr or addr+4)?

It is implementation defined.  It may be simultaneous.  It does not even need to be consistent.

Comment: How is this related to endianess?

Comment: @fuz With `volatile uint64_t *test = (volatile uint64_t *)(addr);`, we do not know if the LS 32-bits are in the lower address or the MS 32-bits or what. As OP asked about "Store ordering", that could imply the sequence of the saves and/or the endian on the saves.  In OP's case, both are _implementation defined_.

Comment: Oh I see.  I have never seen the term “endian(ess)” used in reference to store order.

Comment: @fuz I would suggest that is the most usual context.  There are issues of both time-order and address order.  The first question is unclear which is meant, even the second is ambiguous - first in memory or first in time?  It probably does not matter, since the C standard has nothing to say on either.