# How can I declare a variable not to be optimized (put into register) in order to debug in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, gdb

I'm developing a simple application in **C++/Qt**, and I have the following declaration:

`QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;`

I'm debugging the application using **gdb**. I set a breakpoint, it works fine, and the debugger hits the line. But if I try to inspect the object declared above I get this output:

> ```
> -data-evaluate-expression --thread 1 --frame 0 layout 
> ^done,value="<value> optimized out>"
> ```

I read that this message, `"<value> optimized out>"`, occurs because the compiler optimized the code, and put the data into the register. I'm using **g++** compiler, with flag `-O0` (none optimization) set.

Is there something I'm missing, or does it exist a way to declare a variable not to be optimized, say, as opposed to the storage specifier `register`? I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick, kernel 2.6.35-24.

**EDIT1**

Some more code:

```
WorkspaceChooserDialog::WorkspaceChooserDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle(tr("Select a workspace location"));
    QLabel *wpLabel = new QLabel(tr("Workspace:"), this);
    QLineEdit *wpLineEdit = new QLineEdit(QDir().homePath(), this);
    QPushButton *okButton = new QPushButton(tr("OK"), this);
    QPushButton *cancelButton = new QPushButton(tr("Cancel"), this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

    connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect(cancelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));

    qDebug() << "begin: " << layout << " :end";
    layout->addWidget(wpLabel, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(wpLineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    layout->addWidget(okButton, 1, 1);
    layout->addWidget(cancelButton, 1, 2);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

**EDIT2**

For reasons unknown to me, after I compiled with verbose mode `-v` flag set, the error didn't appear anymore, even after unsetting it again. Now gdb creates the variable, and I'm able to inspect its value.

For who are interested, the compiler's flags set are:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

Comment: Being put in a register is not the only possible optimization that may have occurred here.

Comment: could you check your compiler logs? probably you have somewhere overwritten your -O0 ?

Comment: should you have '()' QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout->HERE<-; ??

Comment: @fazo: The empty parenthesis are optional if the class contains a default constructor. It will slightly change the meaning for POD types (will force default-initialization) but for types that have non-implicitly defined default constructor the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 3):

What other compiler flags have you set?

Try:

```
-g -O0 -fno-inline
```

Comment: Please, see **EDIT1** on my question.

Comment: @kaneda: so is this question answered now?

Comment: It was resolved in a way different from the answers, although I don't know exactly why. That's why despite the useful answers, I didn't marked a correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `volatile`. Maybe, it'll help you!

[Why do we use volatile keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-volatile-keyword-in-c/4437555#4437555)

Comment: Interesting explanation. Unfortunately, with `volatile`, gdb tells me `Error: Unable to create variable object`

Comment: @kaneda: can you post more code so that we can understand your problem better?

Comment: Please, see **EDIT1** on my question.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to force a variable to be allocated is to copy a pointer to it to a global variable.

```
QGridLayout **dummy; // at file scope

//...
dummy = &layout; // in function
```

This will force the compiler to spill the variable to memory before calling any non-inlined function, as it cannot prove that the function would not access the variable directly.

This may, of course, have performance impacts, but they're likely to be small compared to the cost of calling the GUI member functions on QGridLayout.

Comment: I was thinking something similar; declared a pointer on the global scope, to force compiler to place a pointer to it in memory. But what I did was just `QGridLayout *dummy; // global scope` but I guess its slighty differente.

Comment: That only forces the object _pointed to by_ layout to be flushed to memory; this is already implied by calling functions on layout. The key is to force the pointer variable itself to be flushed to memory where gdb can get to it.