# Program crash in release build

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, crash

in debug it works fine but when I run the C++ 2010 program in release build (not started from the debugger of visual studio) it crashes. If I comment the lines after the second char*-wchar* conversion it works. Why?

```
void myfunction(const char *dataBuffer)
{
    size_t buffer_size;

    mbstowcs_s(&buffer_size, NULL, 0, dataBuffer, _TRUNCATE);

    wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[buffer_size + 1];

    mbstowcs_s(&buffer_size, buffer, buffer_size, dataBuffer, _TRUNCATE);

    std::wstring archive_data(buffer);
    std::wstringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
    boost::archive::text_wiarchive archive(archive_stream);

    ...

    delete [] buffer;
    buffer = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because of an uninitialized variable (in debug mode most variables are Initialized to zero but are uninitialized in release)

Most bugs like this can be fixed by fixing all the warnings generated by the compiler (warnings are really logical errors rather than syntax errors). So set you warning level higher re-compile make sure you get zero wanings.

In dev studio set the warning level to four, also set the flag to treat warnings as errors.

Ps. Rather than dynamically allocating a buffer with

```
wchar_t*  buffer = new char_t [<size>];
```

Use a standard vector (it's exception safe)

```
std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(<size>);
```

You can get a pointer to the buffer with:

```
&buffer[0]
```

Also: Jen (who deleted his answer) has a good point )I'll delete this and up-vote Jen if he un-deletes his answer.

But you may want to check that the string is correctly NULL terminated L'\0'.

Comment: @Martin nothing, I fixed the 3 warnings (they were about long to float conversion), recompiled but it still crashes. If i remove the lines about boost deserialization it works

Comment: @Stefano: I am not an expert with mbstowcs_s() does it L'\0' terminate the string. This line `std::wstring archive_data(buffer);` expects the string to be null terminated.

Comment: @Stefano: `if (buffer[buffer_size] != L'\0') { std::cout << "ERROR\n";exit(1);}`

Comment: @Martin I tried everything, the wchar_t* arrays are all NULL-terminated now. I cannot use an std::vector. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Martin it seems that the program crashs in another point of the program now. Thank you anyway, you suggestion about NULL-terminated thing was correct to fix one bug

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes compiler attempts to optimize the values which may not allowed to change in the middle of the program.

To notify the compiler to avoid optimization for the particular variable declare as 
[volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-volatile-keyword-in-c) variable.