# Java Threads not stopping with boolean variable control

Tags: java, multithreading

I am implementing a class to ilustrate thread's priorities.

The code is:

```
class ThreadPriority extends Thread {

    private int c = 0; //Counter
    private boolean stop = false;

    public int getCounter() {
        return c;
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        stop = true;
    }

    //El método run simplemente incrementa el contador mientras no se le obligue a detenerse
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            c++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creamos los 3 hilos
        ThreadPriority h1 = new ThreadPriority();
        ThreadPriority h2 = new ThreadPriority();
        ThreadPriority h3 = new ThreadPriority();

        //assign distinct priorities
        h1.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        h2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        h3.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        h1.start();
        h2.start();
        h3.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            //Ignoramos el tratamiento de la excepción
        }

        h1.stopThread();
        h2.stopThread();
        h3.stopThread();



        System.out.println("h2 (máx priority): " + h2.getCounter());
        System.out.println("h1 (medium priority): " + h1.getCounter());
        System.out.println("h3 (low priority): " + h3.getCounter());
    }
}
```

I'm confused because the main thread never ends. It never exits with 0 (or another) code.

Furthermore, the counters displayed are not the expected values, with higher values to higher priorities.

My JVM is running over Windows 10.

This is the output of exection (not ending):

```
h2 (máx priority): 1189029318
h1 (medium priority): 1165120770
h3 (low priority): 1209305976
```

I suppose this is related to synchronization os threads. But if the counter values are displayed, then it means that the callings to stopThread() are executing.

Why this occurs?

Comment: You've written some "tight loops", and these may hog the CPU, preventing other threads from sharing it. Have you considered putting a brief sleep statement within the loop?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `stop` be declared `volatile`? Otherwise readers from other threads may see a non-updated value.

Comment: My first thought would be something with `volatile` indeed.

Comment: Also if you have enough idle CPU cores, the threads may never need to be evicted.

Comment: You just need to add volatile to flag `private volatile boolean stop = false;`, see [While loop not ending when flag changed in different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595868/while-loop-not-ending-when-flag-changed-in-different-thread)

Comment: Re, "...the main thread never ends..." Actually it does end. But unlike in certain other languages, that means nothing. A Java _process_ does not end just because its main thread ended. A Java process cannot end until the last of its _non-daemon\*_ threads ends. \[\* Your three `ThreadPriority` threads are non-daemon. All new threads are non-daemon. If you want a daemon thread, you have to explicitly ask for it.]

Comment: I have other simple example that has not a counter, and it only displays a message in the run() function. In this example the stop() function works as expected without the volatile modifier for the boolean value... This is a little confusing... Maybe with more than one attribute it is when it's needed the use of volatile?