# How to elegantly avoid "condition is always true" warning for this particular kind of for-loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-warnings, c89

Say that we have the following for-loop:

```
#define UPPER 0U
int i;
for(i = 0; i < UPPER; i++) {
    /* foo */
}
```

This will produce a `W549: condition is always true` warning, obviously because we get `for(i = 0; i < 0; i++)` after macro expansion. In the actual code, `UPPER` is a pre-compile time parameter (i.e., it is set by some build scripts depending on the target platform etc.) that can take any value from 0 to 255 and thus the loop is not just dead code.

**How can I elegantly avoid this warning when `UPPER == 0`?**

Obviously, one can wrap the for-loop in an if-statement:

```
#define UPPER 0U
if(UPPER != 0U) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < UPPER; i++) {
        /* foo */
    }
}
```

But that's not what I'd call elegant.

Comment: 1) did you try to compile your sniplet? `#define` should have no `=` and `;`.  2) in your example the condition is false at first try, so the loop will be skipped completely.

Comment: @Serge: No, I just typed it in thinking "what could *possibly* go wrong with this small snipped". For the second point: yes, if `UPPER` is defined as 0. But as I tried to explain in the question, this is a pre-compile parameter, i.e., it may have other values than 0 and thus the for-loop is not dead code.

Comment: @AjeetShah: To make sure I understand correctly: You are suggesting to introduce a new variable, say `volatile int upper = UPPER;` and use that one in the for loop?

Comment: A [volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-volatile-keyword-in-c) variable might help.

Comment: I see warning: `comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]` when using `#define UPPER 0U` but no warning when using `#define UPPER 0`. Is it necessary to use unsigned UPPER?

Comment: @AjeetShah: No, unsigned is not neccessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap it in code, wrap the code using conditional compilation:

```
#if UPPER > 0
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < UPPER; i++) {
      /* foo */
  }
#endif
```

The elegance stems from:

- No dead code when `UPPER` is 0.
- Completely portable to any C compiler since 1970-01-01
- Easy to read and understand

Answer (score 1):

Not a good style of coding, but solves the task. g++ eliminates the dead code even when optimization is off.

```
#define UPPER 0U
int i;
for(i = 0; &((char*)0)[i] < &((char*)0)[UPPER]; i++) {
    /* foo */
}
```

Comment: This adds a dependency on a specific C++ compiler to C code. That's at least as ugly as the code needed to make this work as advertised.

Comment: Why? any C compiler should accept this construction. BTW, Also, the commonly used OFFSET macro implemented using the same techniques.

Comment: Because you talk of a C++ compiler, not a C compiler, that's why it adds a dependency on C++, according to what the words suggest. If you meant it in another way, it's at least hard to understand. The uglyness of the code is obvious, though. Using address-dereferencing of arrays instead of plain int? Whoa! :-)

Comment: I talked about g++ as gcc (I use 4.8.3) does not produce such warning at all, at least I did not succeed to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

It eliminates warnings of comparison of `signed` with `unsigned` and prevents compiler from optimizing the code.

```
#define UPPER 0U
int i;
volatile int u = UPPER;
for(i=0; i < u; i++){
    /* foo */
}
```

Tested compilation with `gcc -Wall -Wextra myfile.c`

Comment: It has one drawback: it breaks the optimization so `i` would not be put in a register.