# Is mutex and/or conditional_variable really needed in this multithreaded program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

Given three functions as below:

```cpp
void print1() {
    cout << "one";
    cout.flush();
}
void print2() {
    cout << "two";
    cout.flush();
}
void print3() {
    cout << "three";
    cout.flush();
}
```

I need to spawn **three threads**, where each thread is for running each function above. We can assume that I have no control over how threads are scheduled by CPU, but these three functions must execute in the right order. That is the output must be "**onetwothree**".

I've read many solutions and materials about [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [conditional_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), and I understand that this task should be solved with them. But I think this task can still be solved with just one normal variable without any multithreading tools, such as mutex, atomic variable, etc. For example, here is my solution:

```cpp
#include <functional>  // function
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
    int turn;

  public:
    Foo() { turn = 1; }

    void first(function<void()> printFirst) {
        while (turn != 1) {
        }
        printFirst();
        turn = 2;
    }

    void second(function<void()> printSecond) {
        while (turn != 2) {
        }
        printSecond();
        turn = 3;
    }

    void third(function<void()> printThird) {
        while (turn != 3) {
        }
        printThird();
        turn = 1;
    }
};

void print1() {
    cout << "first";
    cout.flush();
}
void print2() {
    cout << "second";
    cout.flush();
}
void print3() {
    cout << "third";
    cout.flush();
}

int main() {
    Foo f;

    thread thread3([&]() { f.third(print3); });
    thread thread2([&]() { f.second(print2); });
    thread thread1([&]() { f.first(print1); });

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Essentially, a public attribute `turn` in `Foo` is used to control the flow of the running threads. And I specifically spawn `thread3` first to show that `turn` variable can indeed control `thread1` is executed before `thread3`. I've run this program several times and the result is consistently showing "onetwothree".

So, my question is, given the setting of the task, are there any **loopholes** in my solution?

I can only think of one *possible* loophole, which is that the comparison operation `turn != 1` and the assignment operation `turn = 1` may not be atomic, which will result to race condition. But based on my research, the comparison operation and the assignment operation of a variable is atomic. Thus, can I say that my solution is foolproof?

Comment: "based on my research, the comparison operation and the assignment operation of a variable is atomic". I'm curious what you found in your research that said that about the C++ language.  Yes. you must use a mutex.  Even your while loops are UB.

Comment: At a minimum, turn should be declared volatile.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-the-volatile-keyword   Additionally, polling in the manner you've presented will unduly consume processor cycles and slow everything down.  In comparison, waiting on a condition variable, puts the thread to sleep, a state in which it does not consume processor cycles, until the condition variable is notified.

Comment: Your loops using `turn` to control a loop have undefined behaviour (like all infinite loops with no observable behaviour).  If they work for you, then you just got lucky (with your compiler and host platform) - there ARE real-world compilers that simply optimise by removing such loops entirely (another perfectly reasonablw outcome of undefined behaviour). Your functions access/modify shared objects  (`turn` and `std::cout`) without synchronisation, so also have undefined behaviour - synchronisation primitives such as `std::mutex` or conditional variables provide options to address that.

Comment: @jonno Volatile is WRONG.   You do NOT use volatile for thread synchronization.  Never.

Comment: I think what @xaxxon was trying to say was that volatile should not be used because it fails to address the effects of hardware-level memory caching in a multi-processor environment, whereas std:atomic does, at least to some degree.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819095/concurrency-atomic-and-volatile-in-c11-memory-model

Comment: No, it's wrong because C++ says it's wrong not because of anything about the underlying hardware.   You don't use volatile for thread sync.  C++ is not defined by the underlying hardware.

Comment: @JerryCoffin can you try to either be helpful or just move along?

Comment: Thanks for all the insights regarding this naive question. Sometimes I think learning _why_ my intuitive (wrong) solution is wrong is as important as learning the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first, and biggest loophole is that `turn` is a non-atomic type and yet you are accessing it from multiple threads without any synchronization, which invokes undefined behavior.  In particular, the compiler is allowed to assume if the current thread doesn't modify a non-atomic/non-synchronized variable, then that variable's value will remain constant, so e.g. it could (and very well may) implicitly replace your `while(turn!=1){}` logic with something more efficient, like `if(turn!=1) {while(1){}}`, causing your thread to spin the CPU forever (even after another thread executed `turn=1` !).

You could close that loophole by changing `int turn;` to something like `std::atomic<int> turn;`, to let the compiler know that multithreaded/unsynchronized access to `turn` is expected and should be handled carefully... or alternatively you could introduce a mutex, and make sure that all reads and writes to `turn` happen only while the thread has the mutex locked.

That leads to the second problem, which is that even if you manage to get to well-defined behavior, busy-looping on a variable like that is horrifically inefficient.  Your program might spend billions of CPU cycles needlessly re-testing the state of `turn` before `turn`'s value finally changes to what is expected; when a mutex/condition-variable based solution would only need to test it once or twice and could spend the rest of that time sleeping (and therefore not draining the computer's battery and not taking CPU cycles away from other programs that also might be running).

Worse than that, most modern OS's have schedulers that notice when an application is hogging the CPU and respond by automagically reducing that application's scheduling priority (to allow other non-CPU-hogging programs to still respond quickly to the user), so if your program is wasting CPU cycles like that, it will quickly find itself only getting whatever crumbs of CPU time are leftover (if any) once all other executing tasks have already had their chance to run as much as they want.

TL;DR:  you really don't want to "roll your own" synchronization this way.  Learning how to properly use mutexes and condition variables is 100% necessary and worth the effort, if your goal is to write multithreaded software that works well.

Comment: It can replace the loop with nothing.   It is a malformed program.  It could just assume that that loop must be unreachable.

Comment: actually what it can assume is that the while test always fails because if it doesn't, there's nothing that can possibly change that value, so the loop will just be tossed out.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing and modifying a non-atomic variable from multiple threads is undefined behaviour. Given this, the compiler can assume that your while loops are infinite which is also undefined behaviour.

Whilst your code might appear to work correctly in your current environment it can and does fail in others. For example running with gcc with optimisations enabled produces incorrect output https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0af81410f8dbb04b

Making `turn` atomic would fix the problem but it'd still be much more efficient to use a mutex and condition variable.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the headline question is no. You don't need a mutex or condition variable--you can do the whole thing with (for example) atomic variables. That's how lock-free programming is done. But getting lock-free code correct is generally quite a bit more difficult than using locks correctly (though under the right circumstances, it can reduce overhead and/or give some guarantees that lock-based programming can't).

In this case, there is an easy way to do things that avoids using any mutex, condition variable, or much of anything else. Since the assignment requires you to use three threads, but only actually do anything serially, we can basically cheat: spawn three threads to meet the requirements, but don't ever run them concurrently at all:

```cpp
int main() { 
    std::thread one = std::thread([] { print1(); };
    one.join();
    std::thread two = std::thread([] { print2(); };
    two.join();
    std::thread three = std::thread([] { print3(); };
    three.join();
}
```

While this doesn't gain anything from using threads, it does at least minimize the damage done by being forced to use threads when we only really want serial execution.

But that probably won't make whoever's teaching the class very happy, so I suppose we need to explore still worse ways of writing the code. If we want to make it work with fairly minimal overhead, we probably want to use a mutex and a condition variable, but at least we can encapsulate that so most of the thread doesn't have to deal with its intricacies.

There are times we want a thread to halt and wait until some other thread has signaled that it can proceed. I'd call this a "Gate". When you reach the gate you stop until somebody opens the gate. Even though we're not making very good use of the tool, at least this way we're creating and using a tool that does have good uses.

```cpp
/// @brief support waiting until somebody opens the gate
class Gate {
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> open_ {false};
public:
    void wait() {
        std::unique_lock L(m);
        cv.wait(L, [&] { return open_.load(); });
    }

    void open() {
        std::unique_lock L(m);
        open_ = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
};
```

This allows us to synchronize the threads as needed with fairly minimal (syntactic) overhead:

```cpp
int main() {
    Gate doTwo;
    Gate doThree;

    std::thread one = std::thread([&doTwo] { 
        print1(); 
        doTwo.open(); 
    });
    
    std::thread two = std::thread([&doTwo, &doThree] { 
        doTwo.wait(); 
        print2(); 
        doThree.open(); 
    });
    
    std::thread three = std::thread([&doThree] {
        doThree.wait(); 
        print3(); 
    });

    one.join();
    two.join();
    three.join();
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If we really wanted to, we could probably go even further with this, so `main` would look something like this:

```cpp
first(print1).then(print2).then(print3);
```

Oddly, given the sequencing involved, it's actually quite a bit easier to implement the sequence in reverse, so it looks something like this:

```cpp
do(print3).after(print2).after(print1);
```

...but almost nobody likes that very well, and I'm not convinced that there's enough use to bother implementing either one.