# Is it safe to change the pointer while it is used for virtual functions calls in other threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a multithreading application two or more parallel threads use a pointer to call virtual function. At the same time in another thread this pointer changes to another object. Is this safe or should I take measures to make it thread safe?

Consider the code:

```cpp
class Scene {
public:
  virtual void render() const = 0;
  virtual void update() const = 0;
};

class D1: public Scene {
    // members
public:
  virtual void render() const { /* work with D1 members */ }
  virtual void update() const { /* work with D1 members */ }
};

class D2: public Scene {
    // members
public:
  virtual void render() const { /* work with D2 members */ }
  virtual void update() const { /* work with D2 members */ }
};
// …somewhere in thread 1
Scene *scene=new D1;
…
Scene *scene=new D2;
// … somewhere in thread 2
scene->render();
// … somewhere in thread 3
scene->update();
```

**Why I consider it risky**

If the virtual function call is not an atomic operation, I can imagine situation when compiler takes the pointer to the object (to be implicitly passed is *this*) in one step and refer to virtual function call in another step, again reading this pointer from memory. Between this steps the *pointer could be changed in another thread* and this could end up with method D2::render called for D1 object.

I am not even sure that making this pointer *volatile* would help compiler to fix this, since it is chance that compiler uses this hint for slightly other purposes.

**My simple workaround**

Simple workaround for this would be to use an intermediate copy:

```cpp
// … somewhere in thread 2
Scene* safe_copy_scene = scene;
safe_copy_scene->render();
```

The question is, is it necessary or the virtual function call could be considered atomic from this perspective and this is guaranteed by standard and doesn’t depend on compiler/optimization?

Comment: If you have a variable shared between 2 or more threads, and at least one of those threads is a writer, then you need synchronization around the modification and access.  Without that you have a data race and that is UB.

Comment: its not just risky but wrong to call a non-const method concurrently on the same object without any synchronisation.

Comment: "the pointer could be changed in another thread " when you are talking about the implicit `this` pointer, that cannot be changed. What you need to concern yourself with here is whether the state of the object that `this` points to changes.

Comment: fwiw, the issue is not about the virtual method call, but already `Scence* x = scene;` in one thread while another thread does `scene = new D1;` is a data race.

Comment: @NathanOliver, if your statement was correct, how all pointer-based lock-free approaches work? I have lot of perfectly working code where the pointer is used to switch between buffers in lock-free architecture since pointer replacement in that cases are atomic operation. So, this is definitely not true for atomic operations and variables.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, well modification and synchronization is another topic. To make the question more straightforward I updated it with `const` modifiers. For the moment I care about reading and "atomicity" of virtual function call. Please see the details in my "Why I consider it risky" section and step based scenario from 273K in their answer below. So, by mine and their sights this is risky even for reading, isn't it?

Comment: @DamirTenishev the issue with that is that the C++ standard doesn't know about those things.  the only atomic type is `std::atomic`.  It might wind up being a do nothing wrapper, but without it your atomic variables aren't really atomic and you are in UB land.  The compiler might chose to do some optimization and break your code at any time.

Comment: @DamirTenishev With atomic instructions. Explicit atomic instructions. These form essentially memory barriers, where the compiler is *forced* to generate instructions that *load* the variable from global memory into a local variable, and not to assume that the variable can simply "alias" global memory and would remain a constant past the point of the "copy".

Comment: @PeteKirkham, I am not speaking about *this* during the function execution. Of course, it couldn't be changes, it is a copy, passed as an implicit argument. The question is that is could be different than *this* used to calculate in vtable. See the scenario in the answer from 273K below. It explain my concerns pretty well.

Comment: @DamirTenishev You misunderstand / overestimate how much your request for a "copy" means to the compiler. It means nothing. By definition, no other thread can change the globally visible variable without a synchronization primitive or other barrier. And that very definition permits the compiler to IGNORE that you tried to copy it beforehand.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, on your second comment, why is it a data race while both are atomic operations?

Comment: @NathanOliver, that's what I care about. Not sure what you mean with "the only atomic type is std::atomic". For example here [24.4.7.2 Atomic Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html) it is stated: _In practice, you can assume that int is atomic. You can also assume that pointer types are atomic; that is very convenient._ I have lots of code written on this assumption and it never let me down.

Comment: @Ext3h, so what would be the canonical solution for this?

Comment: @DamirTenishev that is a guide from an implementation, not the C++ standard.  C++ supports many platforms and if you want your code to be 100% compliant, you need `std::atomic<T*>` if you want to guarantee that the pointer operations are atomic.  You have to decide how portable do you want your code to be.  On x86-64 systems for example `std::atomic<T*>` is basically a non-op wrapper since we know it is atomic on the hardware.  You still need the `std::atomic<T*>` so the code is standard compliant and the compiler knows not to do some possible optimizations that could have an effect.

Comment: @DamirTenishev You are confusing stuff. `int` has only a subset of the properties of a true atomic access, in the sense that you can't get the error class of ***partial*** reads/writes which leads to complete garbage values. But you still don't get *repeatable* reads. Which is the real issue here, which can even bite you on x86-64. `safe_copy_scene = scene.load()` is safe when `scene` is an `std::atomic`, you say explicitly "You must read this only ONCE.

Comment: "why is it a data race while both are atomic operations?" because they arent atomic operations as far as C++ is concerned.

Comment: @Ext3h, on your second comment. In "My simple workaround" I make an explicit variable which couldn't be changed during the virtual function call in no way even in multi-threading environment, since it is no longer a shared `scene` variable. Are you saying that compiler is permitted to optimize out this variable even if `scene` variable would be declared _volatile_?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I see it, thank you. In case I have not `Scene*`, but actually `std::shared_ptr<Scene>', is the a chance to use 'std::atomic' properly?

Comment: @DamirTenishev [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2)

Comment: @DamirTenishev https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2

Comment: @Ext3h, can you please provide an example of *repeatable reads* which could make harm to me in this case? I mean, if I take a reservation that I don't care if other threads jump to a new `scene` pointer one loop later and care only about wrong reading access of D1/D2 objects, am I still in danger? Could you please help me to realize the scenario?

Comment: @DamirTenishev And regarding `volatile`: It *only* prohibits the compiler from reordering accesses (reads and writes) to `volatile` variables within a *single* thread. It says nothing about multiple threads. And it doesn't work at all as expected with complex types.

Comment: If you can't use C++20, you can use these free functions instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: @DamirTenishev With `std::shared_ptr` this is actually a real issue. You end up with nasty double-frees and revived "zombie" objects as there are *two* pointers in an `std::shared_ptr` plus another one in the control block, and the access to the combination of those isn't even atomic anymore. One thread thinks its the last owner, destroys the object, and while at it the other thread is copying the ptr and the continous to "revive" the already destroyed object. The control block in isolation is threadsafe, but the variable isn't.

Comment: @Ext3h, thank you. Of course,I don't mean to use it with complex types. I was just curious. For me the main value of volatile was that it forbids the compiler to cache the value,saying that it could be changed by another thread or hardware at any time. So, before any use of volatile variable it must be read from memory. Am I wrong here?
For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-the-volatile-keyword) it prohibits to optimize out the code. So, it makes much more than prohibiting reordering accesses, I believe. I could be wrong, maybe your wording cover cases.

Comment: @DamirTenishev There are odd edge-cases around `volatile` where the compiler may still deduce that you can't possibly do anything sane. E.g. allocating the variable on the stack, never taking its address and passing it to the outside via syscalll or global symbol and then *still* expecting it to randomly change. If you can't prove it was in global memory (in other terms: it wasn't *actually* observable), the compiler may still screw with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe, is a data race and results in undefined behavior.

Imagine such a bad scenario:

```
T1: Scene *scene=new D1
T2: reads vtbl of D1 pointed by scene
T1: scene=new D2
T2: calls D1::render() and passes this pointing to D2.
```

The workaround is not safe, because the compiler can optimize away the `safe_copy_scene` variable.

This is safe:

```
std::atomic<Scene*> scene=new D1;
// …
scene=new D2;
// … somewhere in thread 2
scene->render();
// … somewhere in thread 3
scene->update();
```

The sequenced atomic operations with barriers will not allow to read `vtbl` prior reading `scene` for `this`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the scenario I stated in the "Why I consider it risky" section in my question. If this is true, would "My simple workaround" work and if not, what is the best solution for this?

Comment: No, it will not work. The compiler can optimize your workaround to the original code unless you use `std::atomic<Scene*>`.

Comment: Theoretically, but it would be very odd to implement virtual method calls where you are fetching the `this` pointer twice. Most systems will read scene once into a register or put it on the local function stack, then deref that value for both vtable and data, not go to global memory twice.

Comment: @273K, would it help if I declare the scene variable as `volatile` so that compiler couldn't optimize out its copy?

Comment: @PeteKirkham, of course, this is weird and now my code works just fine. I am just curious if it is still risky, since I don't want to put a delayed bomb here; it could be hard to find the cause when it fires. So, I am looking for a kind of a guarantee.

Comment: @DamirTenishev `volatile` is not a valid thread synchronization technique.

Comment: Use atomics in your workaround. Don't be in [The Fallacy of Premature Optimization](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)

Comment: @273K, where do you see a premature optimization here? I am not optimizing at all, I am looking for a suitable solution. What solution would be the best for this case, just to wrap up `Scene*` with `std::atomic` as it is said in comments for the question and for the answer here? If so, could you please update your answer with the recommended solution so that it could help other people who will read the question/answer later?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Think of it this way: If `std::atomic` isn't necessary in your environment, the compiler will optimize it away. If it is necessary, then, well, it places whatever barriers that are needed around your load/stores.

Answer (score 3):

> At the same time in another thread this pointer changes to another object. Is this safe or should I take measures to make it thread safe?

No, it's not safe to make the pointer point at another object without synchronization and yes, you should take measures to make it thread safe.

One way is to make it atomic:

```cpp
std::atomic<Scene*> scene;
```

Note though that if multiple threads are calling non-`const` member functions on the same `Scene` object, you need to make them thread safe as well.

You also need to keep references to the scenes so that they can be properly destroyed when you're done with them and they must not be destroyed before any thread that may access them is guaranteed to not make such accesses anymore.

```cpp
auto scene1 = std::make_unique<Scene>(); // thread 1
auto scene2 = std::make_unique<Scene>(); // thread 2
```

You can then switch the active scene with:

```cpp
scene = scene1.get(); // thread 1
scene = scene2.get(); // thread 2

// any thread after `scene` has stored a scene*:
void func() {
    auto& active_scene = *scene; // picks scene1 or 2
    active_scene.foo();
    //...
    active_scene.bar();          // still the same scene you called foo on
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the example with pointers for the sake of simplicity, in real code I use 'std::stared_pointer<Scene>' which makes very simple assignment of the pointer assignment in `scene=D1scene` or `scene=D2scene` where both D1scene and D2scene are both `std::shared_pointer<Scene>`'s, as well. Why do you prefer 'std::unique_pointer` here? Yes, it is unique, but it complicates things with these `get`'s. Any real issues with usage 'std::shared_pointer` here except some overhead for sharing?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I use `unique_ptr` whenever there's no shared ownership so it's my first choice for that reason in almost all situations. However, there is no such thing as a `std::atomic<std::unique_ptr<T>>` so if you use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` I think you should be fine. The `.get()`s on the other hand should not be plentiful in your code. It's only when you assign to the `std::atomic<Scene*>` that you would need it. Otherwise, use `->` to dereference it just like any other pointer.