# Is libstdc++ wrong to reject assignment of volatile rvalue to std::ignore?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, tuples, language-lawyer

I noticed that libstdc++'s implementation of `std::ignore` takes a `const T&` argument, which can't bind to a volatile rvalue. Hence the following code fails to compile:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
struct C {};
using VC = C volatile;
int main() {
    std::tuple<VC> t;
    std::tie(std::ignore) = std::move(t);
}
```

(http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bfc499c1748e59e)

Is this in violation of the standard, or is there a clause that renders this undefined behaviour?

Comment: Why would you want to use `volatile`  in the first place? It disables optimizations, doesn't make things thread safe. I don't see why you'd do that...

Comment: @JesperJuhl *because it's there*

Comment: Not a good reason. Code can be changed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/why-does-volatile-exist Also, language-lawyer question kind of have the right to ask about nonsense (or weird, at least) cornercases, look at it as a sport.

Comment: This case isn't "non-sense". It's a minimal case demonstrating the issue. If it was a real world example showing a valid use of volatile, people would be complaining that it's not an MCVE.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper Did not claim this was nonsense, stated it doesn't matter.

Comment: @BaummitAugen We're in agreement here. I'm mostly referring to Jesper but pinging him would not make sense since he does not explicitly use the word "non-sense".

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make _much_ sense to ignore a volatile object?

Comment: @Brian `volatile` in general doesn't work well with C++ objects in general. Try this: `volatile std::string s; s = "SSS";`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a language lawyer, so I'm going to be answering this question as directly as possible.

`ignore` is found in the synopsis of `tuple` in [`tuple.general`](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.general) as such:

```
// [tuple.creation], tuple creation functions:
const unspecified ignore;
```

As you noticed, the [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/tuple#L1584) implementation defines `ignore` like this:

```
  // A class (and instance) which can be used in 'tie' when an element
  // of a tuple is not required
  struct _Swallow_assign
  {
    template<class _Tp>
      const _Swallow_assign&
      operator=(const _Tp&) const
      { return *this; }
  };
```

Whereas the [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/95526d31cb9688f74106a58a9e8b5d1f663fcf5a/include/tuple#L1068) version defines it like this:

```
template <class _Up>
struct __ignore_t
{
    template <class _Tp>
        _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
        const __ignore_t& operator=(_Tp&&) const {return *this;}
};
```

As such, it compiles in libc++. Now the definition of [`std::tie`](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.tuple#tuple.creation-7) can be found in [tuple.creation] which says:

> Returns: `tuple<Types&...>(t...)`. When an argument in `t` is
>   `ignore`, assigning any value to the corresponding tuple element has
>   no effect.

This doesn't say anything about `ignore` itself, so I'm going to chalk this up to *unspecified* behavior. You can argue it's *undefined* behavior by omission, but that might be stretching it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't that specify the behaviour well enough so that the code I posted should have *no effect*, which does not appear to give the implementation license to reject the code?

Comment: @Brian *No effect* is in itself under-specified. `std::tie` has no *effects* clause. The `operator=` in `ignore` does nothing but `return *this`, so is a no-op, which perfectly fits under one definition of*no effects*. Either way, the code is rejected because of how the library is implemented, not because of a violation of any of the clauses under `std::tie`.

Comment: No, it doesn't say the function `std::tie` has no effects; it says that "assigning any value to the corresponding tuple element has no effect".

Comment: @Brian That's not what I said. I said it has no *effects* clause, which is sometimes present and sometimes not. The only wording present is *no effects*. So the only thing that follows is pure speculation. (I edited my comment above incase you thought I meant `tie` was a no-op).

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**

```
// g++ 4.8.4
int main() {
    volatile int vi;
    std::ignore = vi;

    // error: no match for ‘operator=’ (
    //     operand types are ‘const std::_Swallow_assign’
    //     and ‘std::remove_reference<volatile int&>::type {aka volatile int}’
    // )
    // std::ignore = std::move(vi);

    // However this compiles:
    volatile int&& vir = std::move(vi);
    std::ignore = vir;
}
```