# Is a global implicitly volatile in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

My question is very simple. The keyword volatile is mandated when you want to tell the compiler that variable could change outside of the scope where it's used, for example a memory mapped variable in an embedded system or a signal handler variable that can change in response to receiving a signal from the OS. 
[Removed the part on thread communication as it's just generating confusion, that's not my question].
[Rephrasing the question to clarify using a comment below]

I think what the OP is asking, **is whether volatile would add further restrictions that are not already imposed by the global nature of the variable (the fact that it's global places certain restrictions on the compiler that are similar to the restrictions that volatile mandates)**.

Comment: Your question text is sprinkled with wrong assumptions. You should read what the `volatile` qualifier means **nad what not**. For instance, it does not provide enough guarantees for multithreading on a typical multi-processor system.

Comment: I'm not saying that it provides enough guarantee for multithreading. I'm just writing an example of when the volatile is suggested to be used (even on a number of answers here on stack overflow). But the question is not if it's enough or not for thread-safety, the question is "when volatile is needed for a global"

Comment: Well, you explicitly mentioned thread communication, so it seem you very well incolude that. To me your question shows no research and is too broad. Plus the multiple false assumptions.

Comment: _when volatile is needed for a global?_ You provided the answer yourself, "when the variable could change outside of the scope where it's used"

Comment: @SandBag_1996: so, when is this needed for a global? please provide an example.

Comment: example: I have a variable that can only change in an interrupt handler that is triggered by some external pulse.

Comment: @Olaf: I mentioned it because it's given as an answer on this site multiple times, but again: the question is not whether a volatile global is enough for thread safety, the question is when volatile is needed for a global variable? the compiler already know that variable could change in other scopes, being a global. Is volatile implicit for a global?

Comment: Not "modified outside the scope it is used" but "*unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects*" [C11 Standard draft 6.7.3p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p7). Do you see the difference?

Comment: @SandBag_1996. I'm talking about global variables here. You have a global variable that can change in an interrupt handler. Will volatile be *needed* for this global? Why?

Comment: Because interrupt handler is *not* called by any code path in a regular C program. It is called "magically" from the compilers point of view, so we need to tell it that we expect this magic to happen in order the compiler not to spoil it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is a global implicitly volatile in C?

No.

You are mixed up about the `extern` variables and `volatile` variables because they both can't be fully optimized by the compiler because they both can be modified externally.
But that doesn't mean they have the same semantics.

Consider [Link Time Optimzation](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) which is possible for global variables. That means, it's entirely possible for a compiler to have complete information on a global variable and thus optimize it accordingly just like any other variable.
But `volatile` means compiler just can't have *any* assumptions about it. Because it could be modified externally at *run time*.

Thus:

```
volatile int vol_global_var;
```

and

```
int nonvol_global_var;
```

can't be treated as same. Because, with sufficient information, a compiler could completely optimize away `nonvol_global_var`. But it can never do that for `vol_global_var`.

So, when would you make a global variable `volatile` qualified is not different deciding when you'd want make *any* variable to be `volatile` qualified.

Comment: "global variables" don't necessarily have external linkage. And the `extern` specifier is not necessary for external linkage.

Comment: @Olaf Whether the "global variable" that OP talks about has `extern` (external linkage) or the optional keyword `keyword` has been used for the said variable doesn't really change much with respect to this question.

Comment: Thanks, the Link time optimization is the piece of information I was missing here.

Comment: No, but giving wrong information in an answer is nevertheless problematic at best. YOu forget beginners will take every word serious. You should use  the correct standard terms, which here is _storage duration_; linkage is not affected here. Although the storage duration also is irrelevant here, as the same problem can occur with automatic variables.

Answer (score 3):

> Another common example is a variable used by more threads to communicate.

***No***, it is **not**. `volatile` offers no guarantees about concurrent accesses among threads.

> But threads have their own stack so could communicate only through the use of global variables, and for a global variable

Yes.

> and for a global variable, the compiler knows already not to do any particular optimization as it could change from other source files

That's not entirely true. Optimizations always affect operations with no side-effects i.e. that don't alter the observable behavior.

> so I don't understand: is a global implicitly volatile?

I don't see how the things are related and why they should be. Global variables are implicitly `extern` - was that what you meant?

Consider:

```
#include <signal.h>

/*volatile*/ sig_atomic_t signal_caught = 0;
void do_handle(/*...*/)
{
   signal_caught = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    while (signal_caught == 0)
         ;

   /* Continuing execution */

}
```

Here, the compiler may assume the program never ends as under no condition `signal_caught` might change. However, `volatile` forces `signal_caught` to be read at each iteration since it could be changed by `do_signal`.

Comment: ok, let's put in another way: when do you need to declare a global volatile?

Comment: @ad3angel1s: Isn't that pretty much the same as asking what's `volatile` for? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/why-does-volatile-exist?rq=1).

Comment: @ad3angel1s: A common case is signal handlers, which are called asynchronously and thus you need a `volatile sig_atomic_t`, to guarantee atomic r/w and compiler's not interfering.

Comment: It's the same as asking what's volatile for in global variables. Can you please provide an example of a case where a simple global is not enough and you need to declare it as volatile.

Comment: @black : I think what the OP is asking, is whether `volatile` would add further restrictions that are not already imposed by the global nature of the variable (the fact that it's global places certain restrictions on the compiler that are similar to the restrictions that `volatile` mandates).

Comment: The signal handler uses a global variable? If it's the case, it wouldn't work as a simple global (not volatile)? Why?

Comment: Exactly @SanderDeDycker.

Comment: Have you looked at the standard link I've provided in the comments above?

Comment: @ad3angel1s I think there is a big hole in your understanding of what volatile variables are, and how they are used in general (global/local or otherwise). Please look at the link that black has provided in comments (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/why-does-volatile-exist?rq=1) which explain about volatile.

Comment: That's not the question @SandBag_1996. The question is, as rephrased above, and still I haven't seen any answer to that. In other terms again, which are the restrictions further imposed by volatile that a global variable doesn't have by its nature already? An example case where volatile is needed on a global.

Comment: @ad3angel1s: I've added an example.

Comment: @black: from your example: signal_caught being a global, it could be changed from other source files, this would prevent the compiler making any assumption on that, or not?

Comment: @ad3angel1s: If you wanted to help the compiler, you'd make it `static`, `const` or both. A global can be changed, but the compiler thinks in terms of translation units: it assumes it may change, it doesn't know if it does though. `volatile`, in these terms, gives close to no help.

Comment: Saying that use of volatile is generally discouraged for MT code is one say, saying it's useless is very different. "_volatile offers no guarantees about concurrent accesses among threads_" That's not true for datatypes typically used for signaling between threads, on typical HW: volatile *does* provide a few potentially useful guarantees for threads. But not sufficiently useful guarantees necessary for inter thread communication in most practical case - and then when you use another thread signaling tool to get those guarantees, you don't need volatile.

Answer (score 2):

No, globals aren't implicitly `volatile`.

And it's hard to write a better answer regarding the use of `volatile` than this:

> **[Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](http://web.archive.org/web/20160208184448/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming)**
>
> There is a widespread notion that the keyword volatile is good for
>   multi-threaded programming. I've seen interfaces with volatile
>   qualifiers justified as "it might be used for multi-threaded
>   programming". I thought was useful until the last few weeks, when it
>   finally dawned on me (or if you prefer, got through my thick head)
>   that volatile is almost useless for multi-threaded programming. I'll
>   explain here why you should scrub most of it from your multi-threaded
>   code.
>
> Hans Boehm points out that there are only [three portable uses for
>   volatile](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2016.html). I'll summarize them here:
>
> - marking a local variable in the scope of a setjmp so that the variable does not rollback after a longjmp.
> - memory that is modified by an external agent or appears to be because of a screwy memory mapping
> - signal handler mischief

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204050/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-henle-is-a-global-implicitly-volatile-in-c).

Comment: The linked Intel article is gone but Hans Boehm's 2006 paper is still up

Answer (score 1):

No, globals are not implicitly volatile.

Your assumption that *threads could communicate only through the use of global variables* is incorrect. All variables, not only globals, can be shared between threads --- for example, by passing their addresses to thread functions.

Threads are not allowed to modify shared variables without proper synchronisation though. This makes it possible for the compiler to still optimize as if threads didn't exist, and without declaring shared variables `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

No.

With non-volatile global variable `int n;`, this code snippet

```
n = 1;
n = 2;
```

could be optimized to

```
store 2 -> n
```

, while with `int volatile n;`, it cannot.