# How to test if boost multi_index has returned an element using find() and end()

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-multi-index

I have not worked with c++ in a few years and am struggling with implementing a boost multi_index container. I've generated a toy that demonstrates my problem here: http://cpp.sh/6q4nb, and (after some typing) I've recreated that code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>

class Placeholder {
    public:
        const uint64_t& getPlaceholderTime( void )  const   { return ph_time; }
        const std::string& getPlaceholderId( void ) const   { return ph_id; }

    private:
        uint64_t ph_time;
        std::string ph_id;
};

struct IndexByPlaceholderId { };

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    Placeholder,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by
    <boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique< boost::multi_index::identity<Placeholder> >
    ,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
        boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<
            Placeholder,
            const uint64_t&,
            &Placeholder::getPlaceholderTime
        >
    >
    ,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
        boost::multi_index::tag<IndexByPlaceholderId>,
        boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<
            Placeholder,
            const std::string&,
            &Placeholder::getPlaceholderId
        >
    >
    >
> currentPlaceholderDatabase;

int main()
{
    currentPlaceholderDatabase currentDb;

    std::string someString = "something";

    volatile auto result = currentDb.get<IndexByPlaceholderId>().find( someString );
    if( result == currentDb.get<IndexByPlaceholderId>().end() )
    {
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FOUND!!\n";
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm searching for an element using find() and then testing if that element is found or not using operator==.  The search I'm doing is using index tagging as explained in the boost [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#tagging).  If it is required that I generate an operator== for this container, can someone demonstrate how to do so as I can't find a clear example in the documentation?

The error I get is:

`57:14: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'volatile boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Placeholder, std::allocator<Placeholder> > > >' and 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Placeholder, const std::basic_string<char>&, &Placeholder::getPlaceholderId>, std::less<const std::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<3, Placeholder, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<Placeholder> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Placeholder, const long unsigned int&, &Placeholder::getPlaceholderTime> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<IndexByPlaceholderId>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Placeholder, const std::basic_string<char>&, &Placeholder::getPlaceholderId> > >, std::allocator<Placeholder> >, boost::mpl::v_item<IndexByPlaceholderId, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>::iterator {aka boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Placeholder, std::allocator<Placeholder> > > >}')`

Followed by the usual long list of candidates due to c++ template options.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must contain the code *within the question itself*.

Comment: Updated to include code in the question.

Comment: Why did you declare `result` to be `volatile`?

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice this question/comment - result was declared volatile to try and resolve a error: binding reference of type 'X&' to 'const value_type {aka const X}' discards qualifiers when I try and pass *result in a subsequent method.  I thought this was the consequence of auto making result const when it shouldn't be because in the subsequent method (not shown here) I need to modify ph_time.  Further, I mistakenly didn't reproduce ph_time's type in my toy above correctly.  It should have been 'mutable uint64_t ph_time'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message unfortunately has the appearance of gibberish because of the multiple levels of templating involved. This is complicated by the way Boost.MultiIndex uses different return types for `find()` and `end()`, expecting either implicit conversions or function overloads to hide that detail from the programmer. Fortunately, the solution is simple: **remove `volatile`**.

Much like a `const` variable cannot be used to initialize a non-`const` reference, a `volatile` variable cannot be used to initialize a non-`volatile` reference. The various declarations that are supposed to make the Boost magic happen do not use `volatile`, so when you declared `result` to be `volatile`, it was left out in the cold.

There should be no harm caused by removing `volatile` in this case. Your `result` variable is not being shared with other processes, so `volatile` accomplishes nothing other than potentially slowing down your code. If you thought you had a reason for using `volatile`, you may want to read [Why does volatile exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/why-does-volatile-exist) In particular, `volatile` does not prevent `const`. Even though they look incompatible at first, a variable can be both `const` (cannot be modified *by the current code*) and `volatile` (can be modified *by something external to the program*).

Comment: Yes, I see now how the volatile led to this situation.  I added the volatile as a guess that auto was causing the type to be const and I'm using result in a method call that is causing an error of binding reference of type X& to const value_type {aka X} discards qualifers.  That is the original problem that I'm back to now.  I'll post a separate question about that if I'm still unable to solve it...