reading an stl container in a different thread after a write
Suppose that we have a global std:: container. I wish to write some things to it, and then have many threads read from it. I will not change it after the initial write.
Is there anything preventing the compiler simply from optimizing accesses by storing them in a register or something of the like? Is a keyword like volatile necessary here? What guarantees am I given that operations on the container are always truly committed to memory?
Even with locks and such, I feel such guarantees are somehow necessary, and in a language like C, I might make them via the use of the volatile keyword.

volatile is the wrong choice for thread sync. in C++. If the data changes happen before the threads are created you should be safe. Concurrent read accesses don't cause a data race. At start of thread, there happens a synchronization, so that all threads should see the same state of data.

Thread creation is a synch point. If you create all the reading threads after the writing thread completes, you should be OK.

BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20volatile%20multithreading, lots of information to be found there.

As long as the write “synchronizes-with” the reads, you should be good. This is also called “release-acquire” synchronization. The semantics are documented here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order
For example, if you use a shared mutex (reader/writer lock), with the writer thread taking an exclusive lock, and all the reader threads taking shared locks, you will get “synchronized-with” semantics and your reads will be consistent with the writes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex
As another example, creating a thread also establishes a “synchronizes-with” relationship between the creating and created threads. Therefore, if you write to the data structure, then create the reader threads, the readers will be guaranteed to see the result of the writes.
It’s also important to note that volatile in C++ does not establish any kind of guarantee of inter-thread synchronization, and so it should never be relied on to force cross-thread data consistency; instead, it will usually just have the effect of impeding perfectly reasonable compiler optimizations.

I'm not using mutexes here. It's just about the actual containers themselves and their memory semantics.

It’s important to note that volatile does not give you any standard guarantee about inter-thread synchronization at all; it only prevents reordering within a single thread. You mentioned “even with locks and such”; locks are entirely sufficient to provide the necessary synchronization.

I'm not asking about synchronization though. I'm asking specifically about guarantees to be committed to memory (even without the usage of locks). The second paragraph is my question.

@user129393192 I’ve added a bit about creating threads to the answer. Do note that if your writer thread and reader threads already exist before the write occurs, then you will need some kind of synchronization operation between them.

The C++ standard doesn’t mandate anything like “committed to memory”. It speaks instead of observable effects, i.e. whether a thread is guaranteed to see the result of a given write or not. That’s why I use the term “synchronized-with” in my answer.

Is there any guarantees made on such observable effects for std:: containers? That is fundamentally my question. As for volatile, how do you mean it gives no guarantees? I had thought a volatile keyword essentially states that changes made to it will be not-optimized (i.e, memory operations on every use and every definition).

The definition is this: if event A in thread 1 synchronizes-with event B in thread 2, then every write made in thread 1 before event A is visible via a read in thread 2 after event B. So, changes to any data structure, including std:: containers, will be visible after a suitable synchronizing operation.

As for volatile, that probably deserves a longer answer, but the short answer is that the C++ standard only mandates that volatile accesses produce visible side-effects within a single thread. It doesn’t guarantee that those side effects are ordered in any way (or even visible to) accesses in another thread. For example, it might be the case that a volatile variable is always committed to a CPU’s cache, but not necessarily in a way that is coherently visible to another CPU. The standard doesn’t mandate that these are literally memory operations; that’s merely the most common implementation.

I apologize for the extended discussion and I can post a different question if necessary, but how is the volatile keyword useful at all then? Single-threaded operations should have "as-if serializability", from my general knowledge of programming languages. I imagine the ONLY case would be something like a signal handler. Not anything like async or something where code executes serially with no interruptions. I'm not sure of the implications for something like thrown exceptions and core dumps.

@user129393192 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/why-does-volatile-exist

Yup, there aren’t many uses for volatile in modern C++. Most uses are deprecated in C++20 (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1152r4.html). For synchronization, standard sync primitives and atomic are preferred. volatile can still be used in cases where e.g. the variable can change from read to read (think device drivers) or to inhibit certain optimizations.
